# Text replacement rules in $FrontEnd?

Tags: front-end

I want to set up a part of my Mathematica package so that typing <kbd><</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> is replaced with the left arrow character (`←` or `\[LeftArrow]`) just like it does with <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I looked briefly at event handling but didn't see anything immediately useful.  I already know, of course, that <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> will insert `←`, and that doing so is not that much additional effort, but I'm more interested in the concept involved here.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also see [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4326/5) for  how to set input aliases and input auto-replacements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally you could use:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  InputAutoReplacements -> {"<-" -> "\[LeftArrow]"}
]
```

But this fails because *Mathematica* already parses `<-` differently.  Specifically [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputAutoReplacements.html) states:

> In expression input, automatic replacements can be performed only on strings of characters that correspond to complete input tokens.

You can see that this setting works for other strings, e.g.:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  InputAutoReplacements -> {"stuff" -> "\[LeftArrow]"}
]
```

Then typing (with a space):

```
x stuff
```

Will render:

```
x \[LeftArrow]
```