# Creating the Nabla operator (also known as Del operator) as an operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, operators

How can I define the [nabla operator (also known as Del operator)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del) as a an operator, acting on everything to the right of the operator!

[image]

Also taking `\[Del]^2` would give the second derivivates.

I wish to be able to write `\[Del]f[x,y,z]` and then evaluate it according to the nabla operator.

What I have now, is just a simple expression:

```
Del = {D[#, x], D[#, y], D[#, z]} &
```

But it would be nice to be able to use the actual `\[Del]` for notation.

I've looked at different examples including: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html

But I really don't understand any of what's going on there.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to use Del for the divergence and curl operators. The direct substitution of dot and cross products do not work.

Comment: Your definition of the square is not consistent with conventional practice, where it would give the laplacian instead of just a vector of second derivatives. I don't think it's a good idea to overload `Times` and `Power` with these interpretations. Better use clearly distinct notation to make code easier to understand.

Comment: If you are using v10, please check details sections of `Grad` and `Laplacian`, and related `Div` and `Curl`. These symbols have new input forms quite close to what you're asking for.

Comment: closely related: [Having the derivative be an operator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5030/5478)

Comment: If you now asked me what is the best way to phrase this in Mathematica, I would tell you do define grad, div, curl separately.  What people call the "del operator" is a notational trick that humans, who context into account when reading math, find convenient. But it does not fit well with a language/notation that must be unambiguous, such as a computer language.

Comment: As an aside: I tried using the `Grad` function instead
`Grad[vector1.vector2, {x, y, z}]`
which gives 
`{Subscript[b, x] Subscript^(0,1)(a,x)+Subscript[a, x] Subscript^(0,1)(b,x),Subscript[b, y] Subscript^(0,1)(a,y)+Subscript[a, y] Subscript^(0,1)(b,y),Subscript[b, z] Subscript^(0,1)(a,z)+Subscript[a, z] Subscript^(0,1)(b,z)}`
What are the superscript referring to?

Comment: $f^{(1,0)}$ is how Mathematica formats `Derivative[1,0][f]` in StandardForm.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this conventional form to a more "mathematically" familiar form?

Comment: Yes, that is done automatically.  Try `HoldForm[Curl[v, {x, y, z}]]` and see how it formats.  This is different from *interpreting* that form when you enter it.  Traditional notation is ambiguous.  When you are talking to a computer you want to be clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 11):

Well, over-pursuing similarity of *Mathematica* code and traditional math notation does more harm than good, still, it's possible to create a nabla operator in *Mathematica*, here's my approach:

```
(*$PrePrint=.*)
$PrePrint = # /. 
    Derivative[id__][f_][args__] :> 
     TraditionalForm[
      HoldForm@D[f[args], ##] &[
       Sequence @@ (DeleteCases[Transpose[{{args}, {id}}], {_, 0}] /. {x_, 1} :> x)]] &;

Clear[$independentVariable, ▽, Δ]
$independentVariable = {x, y, z};
▽ /: ▽ f_ := Grad[f, $independentVariable]
▽·f_ := Div[f, $independentVariable]
▽ /: ▽\[Cross]f_ := Curl[f, $independentVariable]
▽·▽ := Δ
▽ /: ▽^2 := Δ
Δ /: Δ f_ := Laplacian[f, $independentVariable]
CenterDot /: (v_·▽) f_ := Grad[f, $independentVariable].v
CenterDot /: (m_?MatrixQ·▽)\[Cross]f_ := 
 TensorContract[LeviCivitaTensor[3].D[f, {$independentVariable}].m\[Transpose], {2, 3}]
```

Usage:

```
▽ f[x, y, z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
▽·{f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z], h[x, y, z]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
▽\[Cross]{f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z], h[x, y, z]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
▽·▽ f[x, y, z]
▽^2 f[x, y, z]
Δ f[x, y, z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
({Subscript[v, x], Subscript[v, y], Subscript[v, z]}·▽) f[x, y, z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
({Subscript[v, x], Subscript[v, y], Subscript[v, z]}·▽){f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z],h[x, y, z]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Alst = Array[Subscript[A, ##] &, {3, 3}];
vector = #[x, y, z] & /@ {u, v, w};
test1 = (Alst·▽)\[Cross]vector
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the `·` is `\[CenterDot]`, and `▽` is `\[EmptyDownTriangle]` rather than `\[Del]`.

To type `▽` easier, try the technique in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5146/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6726/1871) post.

Not sure if the solution will fail in more complicated cases.

BTW the `$PrePrint` function is modified from the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128127/1871).

Comment: I have merged these questions moving your answer in the process, as requested.

Answer (score 5):

Does it not work as written?

[image]

```
Del = {D[#, x], D[#, y], D[#, z]} &;

∇f[x, y, z]
```

> $\left\{f^{(1,0,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,1,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,0,1)}(x,y,z)\right\}$

---

To extend this in the way that I believe you want you can use the [Notation Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html).

First:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
```

Then paste and evaluate:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{
       SuperscriptBox["\[Del]", "n_"], "expr_"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "\[DoubleLongRightArrow]", " ", 
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{
       RowBox[{"del", "[", "n_", "]"}], "[", "expr_", "]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}]], "Input"]
```

Which should look like this in the Notebook:

[image]

(Or enter the equivalent using the Notation Palette.)

Then add these definitions:

```
Del = del[1];

del[n_Integer?Positive][expr_] := D[expr, {#, n}] & /@ {x, y, z}
```

Finally:

[image]

> $\left\{f^{(1,0,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,1,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,0,1)}(x,y,z)\right\}$
>
> $\left\{f^{(2,0,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,2,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,0,2)}(x,y,z)\right\}$
>
> $\left\{f^{(3,0,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,3,0)}(x,y,z),f^{(0,0,3)}(x,y,z)\right\}$

Comment: It does seem to Work for just

\\[del], But do you also know if there is any way to make mathematica interpret the \\[Del]^2f[x,y,z] as the second derivatives of the function f[x,y,z]?

Comment: @TehHO Possibly so, but my first attempt failed.  I'll work on it.

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, `\[Del]^2` represent `Laplacian` and there is no definition for `\[Del]^3`, see the corresponding wiki page for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
grad[f_] := {D[f, x], D[f, y], D[f, z]}
```

then

```
grad[x + y]
```

returns

```
{1, 1, 0}
```