# Converting to traditional form of partial derivative

Tags: output-formatting, calculus-and-analysis

How to convert the expression 
Derivative[1, 0][f][r, z]
into the following in Mathematica automatically
D[f[r, z], {r, 1}, {z, 0}]
(or to traditional form of D[f[r, z], {r, 1}, {z, 0}])

Comment: If it is only about formatting it nicely then: [How to make traditional output for derivatives](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23664/5478)

Answer (score 5):

Not too hard:

```
Derivative[2, 0, 1][h][p, q, r] /. Derivative[id__][f_][args__] :> 
TraditionalForm[Inactive[D][f[args], Sequence @@ Transpose[{{args}, {id}}]]]
```

[image: a derivative in TraditionalForm]

Slightly more elaborate:

```
Derivative[2, 0, 1][h][p, q, r] /. Derivative[id__][f_][args__] :> 
TraditionalForm[Inactive[D][f[args],
                Sequence @@ DeleteCases[Transpose[{{args}, {id}}], {_, 0}]]]
```

[image: a derivative in TraditionalForm, with some variables removed]

Even more elaborate:

```
Derivative[2, 0, 1][h][p, q, r] /. Derivative[id__][f_][args__] :> 
TraditionalForm[Inactive[D][f[args], 
                Sequence @@ (DeleteCases[Transpose[{{args}, {id}}], {_, 0}] /.
                             {x_, 1} :> x)]]
```

[image: still another derivative in TraditionalForm, with some variables removed]

Comment: It will be nice if we can format the output with function name h only, that is without the varaibles p,q,r

Comment: You can do the modification yourself; change `f[args]` in the replacement rule to just `f`.

Comment: @Subin This is not what the quesiton is about. If you just want to make custom formatting then say so, and probably the asnwer I've linked is a duplicate. Otherwise you should accept everything which leads to `D[f[r, z], {r, 1}, {z, 0}] // Hold // TraditionalForm`.