# Getting Mathematica to supply derivatives in standard format

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I will like to use the results of Mathematica outputs in formatted text for students. However, I do not know how to get rid of the variable arguments and the use of raised indices to indicate differentiation. These could be removed manually, but can I automate their removal?

For example, when I issue the command,

```
   Div[T[x,y,z],{x,y,z},"Cartesian"]
```

I get terms retaining the functional dependencies explicitly. The output becomes more convoluted with curvilinear systems. I also get the derivatives in the form of raised indices. Is there a way to remove the variable arguments from the output without needing to do it manually? How can Mathematica be made to output the derivatives in the proper traditional form without recourse to raising indices for each derivative?

Comment: Look up `TraditionalForm` in the documentation and see if will help you.

Comment: Another related post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128126/1871

Comment: see also [mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/)

Comment: Thanks especially to xzczd. My problem solved