# Mathematical Notation

Tags: front-end, notation

If we use *Mathematica* notation the following works:

```
Div[Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
```

also if we multiply the gradient with a scalar:

```
Div[scal[x,y] Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
```

But when I use graphical mathematical notation with the Del operator (<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>), the first still works, but the second screws up (sorry, I can not paste the input here, because if I paste the graphical input it gets translated into: `Subscript[\[Del], x, y]` what is interpreted differently in *Mathematica* ). I denote therefore the operator symbolically by: `delxy`:

```
delxy.(scal[x,y] delxy u[x,y])
```

This gives an error message, complaining that one can not take the divergence of a scalar. Obviously `scal[x,y] delxy u[x,y]` is considered a scalar.

Does anybody have an explanation and possibly a way around for this?

Comment: Interesting, didn't know `∇` can be used in this way, but "because if I paste the graphical input it gets translated into: `Subscript[\[Del], x, y]`" seems to suggest that you're not making it correct in 1st case, either. Perhaps you can [create a GIF](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1058/1871) to illustrate what you've done?

Comment: BTW you may want to read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139647/1871

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have to use `Subscript[∇, {x,y}]` instead of `Subscript[∇, x, y]` to make it work. If you do that, I don't get any problems:

[image]

Copyable input for the left side:

```
\!\(
  \*SubscriptBox[\(∇\), \({x, y}\)] . 
  \((scal[x, y] \*SubscriptBox[\(∇\), \({x, y}\)]\ u[x, y])\)
\)
```

If you don't want to type the braces around the subscripts, you can use the notation package (see below for copyable version of the `Notation[...]` inputs):

[image]

#### Copyable inputs

Copy the following, and select "Yes" when it asks you whether the text should be interpreted:

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{
       SubscriptBox["\[Del]", 
        RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y__"}]], "f_"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]", " ", 
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"Grad", "[", 
       RowBox[{"f_", ",", 
         RowBox[{"{", 
           RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y__"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{
       SubscriptBox["\[Del]", 
        RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y__"}]], ".", "f_"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]", " ", 
   TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"Div", "[", 
       RowBox[{"f_", ",", 
         RowBox[{"{", 
           RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y__"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}]}], "Input"]
```

Example input:

```
\!\(
  \*SubscriptBox[\(∇\), \(x, y\)] . 
  \((scal[x, y] \*SubscriptBox[\(∇\), \(x, y\)]u[x, y])\)
\)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The braces do the job. Playing around with the braces, I found, that there is even an easier way, without using the notation package. One can type: Esc,d,e,l,Esc,Ctrl-,{,x,y,},Ctrl Space.

Comment: @DanielHuber Isn't that the first example in my answer? Or am I missing something?