# Defining symbol shortcuts in the Front End

Tags: front-end, keyboard, symbols

I was wondering (because I could not find any documentation on this) if it is possible to do shorthand abbreviations for domains or could one define them?

E.g.

> In[1]:= Element[p,Complexes]
>   Out[1]= p $\in$ Complexes

to instead do something of the following:

> In[1]:= p <kbd>esc</kbd> elem <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd>CC <kbd>esc</kbd>
>   Out[1]= p$\in\mathbb{C}$

And similarly for others:

$
\begin{align}
\text{Algebraics}: &\text{esc AA esc} \,\mapsto\mathbb{A} \\
\text{Rationals}: &\text{esc QQ esc} \,\mapsto\mathbb{Q} \\
\text{Booleans}: &\text{esc BB esc} \,\mapsto\mathbb{B} \\
%%\text{Naturals}: &\text{esc NN esc} \,\mapsto\mathbb{N} \\
\text{Integers}: &\text{esc ZZ esc} \,\mapsto\mathbb{Z} \\ 
\text{Primes}: &\text{esc PP esc} \,\mapsto\mathbb{P} \\
\text{Reals}:    &\text{esc RR esc} \,\mapsto\mathbb{R} \\ 
\end{align}
$

Comment: I removed `Naturals`, because they are simply `Integers` in Mathematica.

Comment: night owl, the "Shell Hackers proposal" you link to in your profile no longer exists.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Shorthand notations:

All those shorthand notations are [well documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html).

- For double struck letters like $\mathbb{A}$, use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, where `ds` stands for "double struck"
- For script letters like $\mathcal{A}$, use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, where `sc` stands for — you guessed it — "script".

#### Creating your own aliases:

To create your own aliases, use `InputAliases`. I use it to create shortcuts [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4326/5), and that might give you some ideas. As for a simple example, try the following:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> {"AA" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]"}]
```

You should now be able to enter $\mathbb{A}$ as desired.

- If you're sequentially adding new rules as you think of them, you can use the following:

  ```
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> 
      Append[OptionValue[Options[EvaluationNotebook[]], InputAliases], newRule]]
  ```

  This will append the rules to existing ones for the *current notebook*.
- To modify an existing rule, use `CurrentValue` (courtesy Szabolcs):

  ```
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "AA"}] = "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]"
  ```
- To set them for all notebooks across all sessions, you can replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd`. This will write it to your front end's `init.m` (located in `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m`). Alternately, you can also enter these directly in the `init.m`, if you maintain it.

You can create a complete list of rules easily as follows:

```
rules = # <> # -> ToExpression["\[DoubleStruckCapital" <> # <> "]"]& /@ 
    {"A", "B", "C", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "Z"};
```

#### Assigning them to the domains

For your purposes, it is as simple as setting $\mathbb{C}$ equal to `Complexes`, but note that the `Attributes` of `Complexes` won't be copied over.

[image]

Comment: Thank You. It seems though, when you create multiple assignments -> `InputAliases`, the memory only hold the last given one. Is there a way where I could store these into the kernal so that way it will always be available to me whenever mathematica is opened, without the need to re-define them and especially each one of them in a single session?

Comment: @nightowl See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. So for: `InputAliases -> {"AA" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]"}]`, do I need to do one for each domain or can I make a list? I guess where I am not sure is if `InputAliases` a self defined variable or a kernel defined variable? Would I be able to do something of the following: 
`SetOptions[$FrontEnd,InputAliases -> {{"AA" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]"},{"AA" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]"},{"CC" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalC]"},{"BB" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]"},{"ZZ" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]"},}]` and so on. And which one of the two would should be used. 1st or 2nd?

Comment: @nightowl `InputAliases` is an _option_ for notebooks and the frontend. You can pass a list of rules as you've done in the second case. That's why I directed you to [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4326/5)... I create the rules (for that question) by joining strings. You could do something similar to create a rule list and set it for the input aliases. Example: `# <> # -> "\[DoubleStruckCapital" <> # <> "]"& /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"]`.

Comment: Also, you'll have to wrap that in `ToExpression` like: `ToExpression["\[DoubleStruckCapital" <> # <> "]"]`

Comment: @nightowl and RM: Overwriting the previous value is a typical problem with `SetOptions`.  A much better way is using `CurrentValue` like this: `CurrentValue[
  EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "AA"}] = "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]"`.  This will not overwrite the existing definitions.  RM, perhaps you can add this to the answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. BTW, looks like the latex+backtick bug has reappeared. See the third point above under "Creating your own aliases"

Comment: @R.M I know about it, already pinged balpha.  He worked around it in a post by entering the $ signs in a `&...;` form ... maybe you can complain too, it might speed things up.  We have LOTS of these $s.

Comment: I noticed that in version 10.1 the command `OptionValue[Options[EvaluationNotebook[]],InputAliases]` does **not work** in a new notebook. I'll write a new answer with my template code for this.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this give the behavior that you desire?

```
$PreRead = # /. 
    {"\[DoubleStruckCapitalC]" -> Complexes,
     "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]" -> Algebraics,
     "\[DoubleStruckCapitalQ]" -> Rationals,
     "\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]" -> Booleans,
     "\[DoubleStruckCapitalN]" -> Naturals,
     "\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]" -> Integers,
     "\[DoubleStruckCapitalP]" -> Primes,
     "\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]" -> Reals} &;

$PrePrint = # /. 
    {Complexes  -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalC]", 
     Algebraics -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]", 
     Rationals  -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalQ]", 
     Booleans   -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]", 
     Naturals   -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalN]", 
     Integers   -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]", 
     Primes     -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalP]", 
     Reals      -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]"} &;
```

Now you can enter these with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`ds*`<kbd>Esc</kbd> where `*` is the letter, and they will be interpreted as the corresponding domain.  Also, the domains will be printed as a double-struck letter.

As noted in the comments `Naturals` is not a valid *Mathematica* domain but I kept your notation for consistency.

---

To load these for all sessions on start-up, put this code into one of your `init.m` files, probably this one: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`.

For custom input aliases add them to the `InputAliases` list, possibly using the Option Inspector, or with this, but only run it once:

```
old = Options[$FrontEnd, "InputAliases"][[1, 2]];

new = Join[old,
   {"CC" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalC]",
    "AA" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]",
    "QQ" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalQ]",
    "BB" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]",
    "NN" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalN]",
    "ZZ" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]",
    "PP" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalP]",
    "RR" -> "\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]"}];

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, InputAliases -> new]
```

Comment: `Naturals` is not a valid domain in Mathematica

Comment: @R.M I noticed this, but the OP lists it so I did too.  Also, some of the letter choices seem odd to me, but I didn't question them.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks. How would I make this be possible to be stored for all sessions even after shutting it down? And if possible make the shorcut keys more flexible? I am not used to esc ds esc. It just not come right to mind when thinking in terms of domain, but rather the type of letter itself.

Comment: @nightowl see update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I got the `esc` dsR `esc` to print $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not interpreted as the domain of `Reals`. How could I get it like the updated version to be: k  `esc` elem `esc` `esc` RR `esc` $~\mapsto~$ $k \in \mathbb{R}$. where $\mathbb{R}$ represent the `Reals` and **not** just the `\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]`. Also to be automatically loaded for each Mathematica session?

Comment: @nightowl does it work as desired when you define `$PreRead` and `$PrePrint` as shown above?  If it does you can append these definitions to this file for automatic loading: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Okay, but your kind of going over my head. I'm not that familiar with the internal files and kernel of mathematica quite yet. I have not been using it for that long. I am just lost on how to arrange the info needed and what info is needed and which is not needed for what you provided.

Answer (score 2):

First, it hasn't been pointed out yet that the `Notation` package has the command [`AddInputAlias`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddInputAlias.html) which is in principle designed to do what this question requires. There is even a palette for it.

However, if you want to add several aliases all at once, the manual approach of the `Notation` package is inconvenient. One way to automate the creation of shortcuts is this:

```
addInputAliases[rules_List] := 
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  InputAliases -> 
   DeleteDuplicates@
    Join[rules, 
     InputAliases /. 
       Quiet[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]] /. 
      InputAliases -> {}]
  ]
```

Here I query the existing options of the `EvaluationNotebook` and replace the result by an empty list if there was an error getting the `InputAliases` option. I do this because when I open a new notebook (from an existing one) in *Mathematica* version 10, the command `Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]` gives an error which has to be caught.

Now to implement the specific shortcuts in the question, I construct the aliases starting from a list of domains, using the fact that *Mathematica* already *knows* the corresponding abbreviations. They are used automatically in `TraditionalForm` output, so I extract them from that in the list `symbols`, instead of manually entering them. To construct the input `aliases`, I apply simple arithmetic to the character codes of the double-struck symbols:

```
domains = {Complexes, Reals, Algebraics, Rationals, Booleans, 
  Integers, Primes}

(*
==> {Complexes, Reals, Algebraics, Rationals, Booleans, Integers, \
Primes}
*)

symbols = 
 Cases[ToBoxes[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ domains, 
  TagBox[x_, __] :> x, Infinity]

(*
==> {"\[DoubleStruckCapitalC]", "\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]", "\
\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]", "\[DoubleStruckCapitalQ]", "\
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]", "\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]", "\
\[DoubleStruckCapitalP]"}
*)

aliases = 
 Map[(# <> # &), 
  FromCharacterCode[
     ToCharacterCode[#] - ToCharacterCode["\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]"] +
       ToCharacterCode["A"]] & /@ symbols]

(* ==> {"CC", "RR", "AA", "QQ", "BB", "ZZ", "PP"} *)

rules = 
  MapThread[
   Function[{alias, domain, 
     symbol}, (alias -> 
      TemplateBox[{}, domain, DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{symbol}] &),
        InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{domain}] &)])],
   {aliases, ToString /@ domains, symbols}];

addInputAliases[rules]
```

Here are some tests, entered as shown in the image:

[image: screen]

Here is how they are interpreted:

```
I ∈ Reals

(* ==> False *)

I ∈ Complexes

(* ==> True *)

Sqrt[2] ∈ Algebraics

(* ==> True *)

7 ∈ Primes

(* ==> True *)

7 ∈ Integers

(* ==> True *)
```

The way I defined the double-struck symbols using `TemplateBox`, they can also be copied from an output cell into a new input cell without losing the intended interpretation.