# Simpler input for the new unit support

Tags: units

I've been playing with the new unit support in *Mathematica* 9. It seems very useful, but the syntax is very verbose. Instead of typing:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Meters"/"Seconds"^2]*Quantity[1, "Minutes"]^2, "Kilometers"]
```

I would much rather type and read something like:

```
UnitConvert[1 m/s^2*(1 min)^2, km]
```

My first idea was to simply define variables for the units I'm going to use:

```
m = Quantity["Meters"];
km = Quantity["Kilometers"];
s = Quantity["Seconds"];
min = Quantity["Minutes"];
```

but unfortunately, this doesn't really work: The term `0 [any unit]` is always simplified to `0`, and following computations won't work because the units don't match. So for example `UnitConvert[1 m/s^2*(1 min)^2, km]` works fine, but `UnitConvert[1 m/s^2*(0 min)^2, km]` doesn't work, because the first argument to `UnitConvert` evaluates to 0

Are there other ways to achieve this? For example,

- is it possible to prevent the simplification `0 * 1 Meters -> 0`
- is it possible to adjust generalized input so that entering "5 s" would evaluate to `Quantity[5, "Seconds"]`, (like entering $d_x y$ evaluates to `Dt[y,x]` or `n!` evaluates to `Factorial[n]`)

Of course, I've tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> input form first. It's a great way to learn new syntax by example, but I don't think it's practical for day-to-day use, for a number of reasons:

- I can't use notebook expressions in the freeform input. For example:

  [image]
- I can't use 2D input, so I can't even type e.g. $\partial _t$ or $\int _a^b$ within a freeform expression
- Which means that for a longer expression I might have to enter several freeform-input in a single line, which doesn't make it more readable.
- If I do use 2D input like $\int _a^b$, I can't enter freeform-input for *a* and *b* (**EDIT**: Turns out I can. I just have to enter a space before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>. Thanks @Itai Seggev)
- I've been playing with it for an hour. It hung several times and crashed once (Not reproducible) and [I had to restart it once](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15347/unexpected-behavior-of-unitconvert/15348).
- This may be a bit philosophical: I'm using a programming language because I want to express an idea unambiguously. I don't *want* it to guess whether the symbol *t* means a variable for time or metric tons.
- The freeform-boxes look weird in a presentation or publication. Of course, I can convert them to input or display form easily, but (in the right context) an expression like `1920*1080 Bytes*24/s` might mean something to the reader, but `2.0739999999999998*^6B*(24/1s)` doesn't, even if it's the same value.

**UPDATE**: Based on @Leonid's code, this is the best solution I've come up with so far:

```
ClearAll[withUnits];
SetAttributes[withUnits, HoldAll];
withUnits[code_] := ReleaseHold[(Hold[code] /.
      {
       m -> Quantity["Meters"],
       s -> Quantity["Seconds"],
       km -> Quantity["Kilometers"]
       })
    //.
    {
     Power[Quantity[m_, u_]^i_, j_] :> Quantity[m^(i*j), u^(i*j)],
     Times[x_, Quantity[m_, u_]^(i_: 1)] :> Quantity[x*m^i, u^i]
     }];
```

It works for the (few) examples I've tried, like

```
withUnits[a m/s^2 * (3s)^2] /. a -> {0, 1, 2}
```

but I'm not sure if the `Power`/`Times` replacement really covers all cases. Maybe someone can find counterexamples or improve it.

---

Using @Leonid's answer and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15406/5) by rm -rf, I started a package `MyUnits` that looks like this:

```
BeginPackage["MyUnits`"]

Unprotect/@{Quantity,Times};
Quantity/:(0|0.) Quantity[_,unit_]:=Quantity[0,unit]
Protect/@{Quantity,Times};

meter=Quantity["Meters"];
second=Quantity["Seconds"];
hertz=Quantity["Hertz"];
minute=Quantity["Minutes"];
hour=Quantity["Hours"];
byte=Quantity["Bytes"];
kilobyte=Quantity["Kilobytes"];
megabyte=Quantity["Megabytes"];

EndPackage[ ]
```

Using that, I get the simple input I had with the old `Units` package (including command completion) and things like `0 second + 1 hour` still work.

Comment: I wouldn't like to turn so many symbols into operators. But if you can live with a couple of Esc, it is definately simple to add an input alias for a nice small box that displays as you like and parses as `Quantity`

Comment: @Rojo: I have no idea how to do that. Could you add your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: Definately but I won't have either time or a PC for another 2 hours. If that happens and noone has posted it I will

Comment: @nikie [here's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6726/5) a post where I show how to setup input aliases. There are a few others on the site. I won't be able to post something for a while either, but perhaps you can try it out or Rojo will be back

Comment: @IstvánZachar while this is new functionality, it was decided that the current version _does not_ need a [version tag](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80/52), and that the most recent version should be automatically assumed.

Comment: How does McLoone's package handle this sort of problem? It is awhile since I have looked at it but at the time it looked pretty good and I don't recall it being this verbose ...but this stuff is still miles off what MathCAD and Maple deliver their users.

Comment: @rcollyer: Oops, sorry, I totally missed the arrival of v9 and any discussions related.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: The built-in older "Units`" package (which I think is based on AutomaticUnits) will simplify `0*Meters` to `0` too, but it won't mind adding 0 to another quantity or converting 0 to any other unit.

Comment: @nikie have you tried Jon McLoone's units package? You can probably find it in the Wolfram Library.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: But it isn't integrated into Plots and other Mathematica functionality the way the new units are. What I would like would be input like in Units or AutomaticUnits but combined with the deep integration the new Quantities have.

Comment: No need to `Unprotect` `Times`, b.t.w.

Comment: While you can't use 2D input inside Ctrl-=, you can use Ctrl-= anywhere in 2D input.  There is a bug in how Ctrl-= interacts with \[PlaceHolder], but if you type space first and then Ctrl-=, you use it integrals, partial derivatives, and pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a cheap way which does not involve WA, but will only be as good as you make it to be (so that you'd have to customize it yourself): create a dynamic environment:

```
ClearAll[withUnits];
SetAttributes[withUnits, HoldAll];
withUnits[code_] :=
  Function[Null,
     Block[{Quantity},
       SetAttributes[Quantity, HoldRest];
       Quantity /: UnitConvert[arg_, Quantity[_, unit_]] :=
          UnitConvert[arg, unit];
       Quantity /: Times[0, Quantity[_, unit_]] :=
          Quantity[0, unit];
       With[{
          m = Quantity[1, "Meters"], 
          s = Quantity[1, "Seconds"],       
          min =  Quantity[1, "Minutes"],
          km = Quantity[1, "Kilometers"]
        },
       #]],
    HoldAll][code];
```

So that

```
withUnits[UnitConvert[1 m/s^2*(1 min)^2,km]]

(*  18/5km  *)
```

You can set `$Pre = withUnits`, if you want to save some typing. The above function is a hack, of course, but it does dynamic code generation, uses `Block` trick and local `UpValues`, so I decided to post it still.

Comment: How would you solve the `withUnits[UnitConvert[0 m/s^2*(1 min)^2, km]]` problem?

Comment: @nikie I would add this: `Quantity /: Times[0, Quantity[_, unit_]] :=  Quantity[0, unit];`. Not sure it will always work though.

Comment: Neat trick (+1), but if it's only used with `UnitConvert`, wouldn't it be easier to just write a new `myUnitConvert` function instead and substitute it for `UnitConvert`? In other words, what's the advantage of `withUnit` here? I don't have version 9, so maybe I'm overlooking something. (BTW I definitely think online access shouldn't be needed for this).

Comment: @Jens Thanks. The advantage is that this allows you to piggyback on the built-in `UnitConvert` without knowing how it operates, meaning resusing the higher-level abstraction, and that is always better. In essence, my code just generates the same exact code that would be otherwise written by hand, so it can be interpreted as a custom preprocessor written on the level of already parsed code (a macro).

Comment: @Jens Perhaps, let me clarify: the code is being generated inside the `Block`, but then `UnitConvert` fires normally - if it is present in code.

Comment: Ah, now I see the true genius behind it...

Comment: @Jens lol :) The rule of 15 chars minumum per comment sucks.

Comment: It's still not foolproof. For example, the magnitude could be a vector with one component 0 or it could be a variable, that sometimes happens to have the value 0. Ideally, I would like to match *any* product between an expression and a unit, but I couldn't figure out a way to do that for composite units like `m/s^2`

Comment: @nikie True. But making it foolproof may be considerably harder.

Comment: Leonid, what is the purpose of the upvalue on unit convert? It can take a quantity second argument. Also, isn't it dangerous or an overkill to block all Quantity definitions while evaluating the code?

Comment: @Rojo When I tried useing `Quantity` as the second argument for `UnitCOnvert`, it did not work for me. OTOH, my method is producing such code when expanding the abbreviations. So, that rule was a "correction" for my method. Perhaps, it can be recoded to avoid that. As to `Quantity` overload - from what I could see, `Quantity` is an inert head without any rules attached. You may be right if some internal rules exist for it, then we can probably do ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` or just keep it all global. At the time, this code was a quick hack, and I did not really revisit it since then.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications

Answer (score 11):

As noted in the documentation for [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantity.html), you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> to input units.  This uses Wolfram|Alpha, so needs an internet connection.

[image]

`Quantity` will also use Wolfram|Alpha to try to interpret strings, so you could also use:

```
In[8]:= UnitConvert[Quantity["1 m/s^2*(1 min)^2"], Quantity["km"]]

Out[8]= Quantity[18/5, "Kilometers"]
```

Comment: I've tried that first, but I can't imagine entering long formulas with that.

Comment: @nikie Why? You only need 1 Ctrl= call more than the characters you're already typing in your preferred version... If you click the lower box in the above, it'll display the formula exactly as you want in the question.

Comment: @rm-rf WolframAlpha inside Mathematica is really slow for me.

Answer (score 11):

You could set an input alias such as

```
With[{rules = {"m" -> "Meters", "km" -> "Kilometers"}},
 AppendTo[CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], InputAliases], 
  "qu" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, 
    "QuantityUnit", 
    DisplayFunction -> (PanelBox[RowBox[{##}], FrameMargins -> 2] &), 
    InterpretationFunction -> (ToBoxes@
        Quantity[ToExpression@#1, Evaluate[#2 /. rules]] &)]]]
```

Then, <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> brings up a little panel with a couple of placeholders where you write, for example

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could set the styles on a stylesheet, add units to your list of rules, or even not add any. If it doesn't recognize it, it queries WolframAlpha just like `Quantity`, and then caches the result. Setting the input alias to `$FrontEnd` instead of `InputNotebook[]` would make it global and permanent. Or you could add it to the `Notebook` style of some stylesheet instead

Comment: Thanks for the typos and neat keys edits. But why is `Evaluate` necessary?

Comment: Because `Quantity` has the attribute [HoldRest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldRest.html), so code like `Quantity[5, "m" /. "m" -> "Meters"]` remains unevaluated. Maybe you had a couple of copies of the InputAlias in your test notebook, so you didn't notice the problems...

Comment: @Simon, I could swear `Quantity` didn't have that attribute earlier. I had probably been messing with it

Comment: @Simon!!! After the first `TemporalData` use, it's attributes get updated to a simple `NHoldAll`!

Answer (score 8):

For those still preferring the use of AutomaticUnits, Jon has posted a work around to allow its use with v.9 at http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/09/automatic-physical-units-in-mathematica/#comments

Answer (score 7):

Here's my extensions to [Rojo's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15370/34). I've moved the replacement rules into a global variable, to make them easier to modify on the fly

```
$UnitReplacementRules = {"fm"->"Femtometers","nm"->"Nanometers","\[Mu]m"->"Micrometers","mm"->"Millimeters","cm"->"Centimeters","m"->"Meters","km"|"kms"->"Kilometers","mi"->"Miles", "s"|"sec"->"Seconds","min"|"mins"->"Minutes","h"|"hr"|"hrs"->"Hours","yr"|"yrs"->"Years", "\[Mu]g"->"Micrograms","mg"->"Milligrams","g"->"Grams","kg"->"Kilograms", "L"|"l"->"Liters","mL"|"ml"->"Milliliters", "N" -> "Newtons", "K"->"Kelvins","mol"->"Moles","M"->"Molar"}
```

and I've made it cope with compound units with (hopefully) arbitrary 2d structures (e.g., powers and fractions). It also overwrites any existing *qu* `InputAliases`

```
CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], InputAliases] = 
 Append[DeleteCases[CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], InputAliases], "qu" -> _],
  "qu" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, 
    "QuantityUnit", Tooltip -> "Unit Template", 
    DisplayFunction -> (PanelBox[RowBox[{#1, StyleBox[#2, "QuantityUnitTraditionalLabel"]}], FrameMargins -> 2] &), 
    InterpretationFunction -> (With[{unit = #2 /. s_String?LetterQ :> "\""~~(s/.$UnitReplacementRules)~~"\""},
        (*Print[{#2, unit, StringTake[ToString[MakeExpression@#2, InputForm], {14, -2}], KnownUnitQ @@ MakeExpression@unit}];*)
        If[KnownUnitQ@@MakeExpression@unit,
         RowBox[{"Quantity", "[", #1, ",", unit, "]"}],
         RowBox[{"Quantity", "[", #1, ",", "\""~~StringTake[ToString[MakeExpression@#2, InputForm], {14, -2}]~~"\"", "]"}]
        ]] &)]]
```

Some examples:
[image: Examples]

The same comments as in Rojo's answer apply. This is currently set up to add the alias to only the `InputNotebook`, it could be made to add the alias to `$FrontEnd` which would make it work in all notebooks (until it is removed). Note that `$UnitReplacementRules` would have to be added to the `init.m` or something similar if you want this code to work across sessions.

Comment: I just wanted to add a couple of things to the unit handling, so came here to check for new answers. Glad to find you've worked on it.

Comment: I'll probably take your version, move the `DisplayFunction` and the `InputAlias` to a stylesheet, add some way (no idea how yet) to make the "$UnitReplacementRules" remember for ever every conversion made with WolframAlpha. And perhaps if I use it often, make it a shortcut intead of an input alias

Comment: Any other ideas of improvement? Btw, it is not necessarily better but using `Prepend` instead of `Append` I think would effectively override the previous `InputAlias` without actually deleting it

Comment: Those are all good ideas. I think another thing to do would be to make a palette to quickly view and modify the `$UnitReplacementRules`. See the [Grassmann Algebra Package](https://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/)'s palette for something similar.

Comment: @Simon I have greatly improved the number of units supported with this without WolframAlpha. See my answer :).

Answer (score 6):

Improved version of Simon's answer which tries several different transformation of the input string to convert it to the full form that Mathematica needs:

```
Begin["System`"]

(* Deca is intentionally left out as only one character prefixes are supported *)
$SIPrefixes={"Y"->"Yotta","Z"->"Zetta","E"->"Exa","P"->"Peta","T"->"Tera","G"->"Giga","M"->"Mega","k"->"Kilo","h"->"Hecto","d"->"Deci","c"->"Centi","m"->"Milli","\[Mu]"|"\[Micro]"->"Micro","n"->"Nano","p"->"Pico","f"->"Femto","a"->"Atto","z"->"Zepto","y"->"Yocto"};
$UnitAbbreviations={"\[Degree]"->"angularDegrees","\[Degree]C"->"degreesCelsius","\[CapitalOmega]"->"ohms","A"->"amperes","Bq"->"becquerels","C"->"coulombs","F"->"farads","Gy"->"grays","H"->"henries","Hz"->"hertz","J"->"joules","K"->"kelvins","L"->"liters","M"->"molar","N"->"newtons","Pa"->"pascals","S"->"siemens","Sv"->"sieverts","T"->"teslas","V"->"volts","W"->"watts","Wb"->"webers","a"->"julianYears","atm"->"atmospheres","au"->"astronomicalUnit","bar"->"bars","cd"->"candelas","d"->"days","eV"->"electronvolts","g"->"grams","h"->"hours","kat"->"katals","lm"->"lumens","lx"->"lux","m"->"meters","min"->"minutes","mol"->"moles","rad"->"radians","s"->"seconds","sr"->"steradians"};

FirstDropWhile[list_, cond_] := (
    l = LengthWhile[list,cond];
    If[l == Length[list],
        None,
        list[[l+1]]
    ])
StringCapitalize[str_] := ToUpperCase @ Characters[str][[1]] <> StringDrop[str, 1]
ReplaceUnit[str_] := str /. $UnitAbbreviations
    ReplaceSIPrefix[str_] := (Characters[str][[1]] /. $SIPrefixes) <> StringDrop[str, 1]

UnitFullName[str_]:=(
    transformations = {Identity, StringCapitalize,
        Composition[StringCapitalize,ReplaceUnit], ReplaceSIPrefix,
        (ReplaceSIPrefix@Characters[#][[1]]) <> ReplaceUnit[StringDrop[#,1]]&
    };
    candidates = Flatten[{#, # <> "s"}& /@ Through[transformations[str]]];
    FirstDropWhile[candidates, !KnownUnitQ@# &]
)

CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, InputAliases] = 
     Append[DeleteCases[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, InputAliases], "qu" -> _],
    "qu" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, 
    "QuantityUnit", Tooltip -> "Unit Template", 
    DisplayFunction -> (PanelBox[RowBox[{#1, StyleBox[#2, "QuantityUnitTraditionalLabel"]}], FrameMargins -> 2] &), 
    InterpretationFunction -> (With[{unit = #2 /. s_String?LetterQ :> "\""~~(UnitFullName[s])~~"\"" /. s_String :> (s /. "\[CenterDot]" -> "*")},
        If[KnownUnitQ@@MakeExpression@unit,
            RowBox[{"Quantity", "[", #1, ",", unit, "]"}],
            RowBox[{"Quantity", "[", #1, ",", "\""~~StringTake[ToString[MakeExpression@#2, InputForm], {14, -2}]~~"\"", "]"}]
        ]] &)]]

End[]
```

Sorry for the lack of whitespace. I made this using `TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 5):

I gave up trying to use Quantity and the units package in version 9 because of the drop in speed and the clumsy way of incorporating units that makes long expressions difficult to read. I have therefore stuck with Jon McLoone's package that works very well. It can found at http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/09/automatic-physical-units-in-mathematica/#comments

Answer (score 5):

I fully agree that the current Units syntax is cumbersome.  I thus found this thread, which I came upon recently, of great interest.

The various code blocks in the previous answers each offered unique functionality at the time they were written.  Alas, they are currently all either non-canonical, or cause the current version of MMA to crash.

Consider, for instance, the following, which contains a variable for the quantity magnitude:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[z , "Minutes"], "Seconds"]
```

> 60 z s

Neither the myUnits package nor the withUnits module can do the above calculation:

```
UnitConvert[z minute, second]  (*following activation of myUnits*)
```

> UnitConvert[z (1 min), 1 s]

```
withUnits[UnitConvert[z min, s]] (*following activation of withUnits*)
```

> UnitConvert[z (1 min), 1 s]

An additional limitation is that these only work for the particular units or physical constants you've pre-defined.  [I should add that both of these limitations were effectively noted by the author of withUnits, Leonid Shiffrin, who pointed out that his code was offered as a prototype that "will only be as good as you make it to be".] Thus I would say the best application of these two code blocks would be for "production work" (entering many formulas using a known set of units, in a known way), where their speed and simplicity of use would offer great convenience, and you'd be controlling for potential non-canonical behavior by using them under well-tested circumstances.

My typical use case is, however, different — I most commonly do one-offs, in which I may need to use a unit or physical constant I've never used before, or in a way I've never before used it.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> is more suitable for that application, and doesn't fail for the above example, but I find it a bit tedious for long formulas.  For instance, even with the above simple formula, to enter  "min" I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, then type "minutes", then hit the right arrow to get out of the box, then wait for the Wolfram server to respond; only after all this can I enter the comma. This then has to be repeated to enter "s".

Another inconvenience with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> is that you have to change any variable name that Wolfram Alpha interprets as a unit, no matter how obscure.  For instance, you can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to input "wl seconds" (where wl is a variable), since WA interprets that as "wekoliters seconds". [You can enter wl outside the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> statement, but that puts the variable outside the quantity statement, which is not proper syntax and can result in unexpected behavior.]

Having said that, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> is very handy for unit discovery.

Finally, all three versions of the code blocks that create unit-entry-panels cause my version of MMA (11.3 running on MacOS 10.13.2) to crash as soon as I type esc q.

Thus, to add one additional alternative to the mix, I'll offer the very basic approach I use—I simply handle Quantity's cumbersome syntax by creating keyboard shortcuts:

I've set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to give:

```
 Quantity[, ""]
```

And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to give:

```
 UnitConvert[Quantity[, ""], ""]
```

Thus, anytime I need to use Quantity, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, and fill in the rest.  I'd describe this as a compromise that partly addresses Quantity's syntactical inconvenience, while remaining completely canonical. With formulas requiring many Quantity commands, it makes things go much faster.  [Warning: I create the above shortcuts with Keyboard Maestro, which works fine.  However, for additional convenience, you might be tempted to get fancier and make use of Keyboard Maestro's ability to place the cursor at a particular point within the pasted command. Don't do that; it causes unexpected behavior.]

Alternatively, if you want a "production" approach (with the limitations and caveats that entails), you might try the following.  I've not yet found any non-canonical behavior with this approach, but of course there could be corner cases I've not yet encountered:

```
m[uqty_] := Quantity[uqty, "Meters"]
min[uqty_] := Quantity[uqty, "Minutes"]
s[uqty_] := Quantity[uqty, "Seconds"]
k[uqty_] := Quantity[uqty, "Kelvins"]
um[uqty_] := Quantity[uqty, "Micrometers"]
(*etc....*)
```

Units can then be entered with either Postfix (to ensure reliable operation each quantity-unit combination should be enclosed in parentheses)...

```
UnitConvert[(z // min), (1 // s)]
```

> 60 z s

...or Prefix (less typing, but requires entering the quantity after the unit, which may take some getting used to):

```
UnitConvert[min@z, s@1]
```

> 60 z s

Note that to just enter, say, "Seconds", it is necessary to include a "1", i.e., "(1//s)" or "s@1".  Note also that it doesn't accept composite units; units must be entered separately, e.g.:

```
Integrate[(9.8 // m)/(1 // s)^2 *t, {t, (0 // s), (10 // s)}]    
Integrate[m@9.8/(s@1)^2 *t, {t, s@0, s@10}]
```

> `490. m`
>   `490. m`

It also works with FormulaData:

```
FormulaData[{"PlanckRadiationLaw", "Wavelength"}, 
{"T" -> k@5000, "\[Lambda]" -> um@\[Lambda]}]
```

> $\lambda \neq 0\land \text{L}(\lambda )=\frac{1.19104\times
>    10^{14}\text{Pa}/\text{s}}{2.71828^{2.87755/\lambda } \lambda ^5-1. \lambda ^5}$