# Should 0 * 5ft be 0 or 0ft?

Tags: arithmetic, units

After playing with the new quantity system in Mathematica 9 for a while, I keep stumbling over this issue:

```
0 * Quantity[1, "Meters"]
```

is not the same as

```
1 * Quantity[0, "Meters"]
```

The first is dimensionless 0, the second is 0 meters, and a dimensionless quantity can't be added to or converted to a length like meters.

Take e.g. this simplified example:

```
startPoint = Quantity[1, "Meters"];
endPoint = Quantity[5, "Meters"];    
Manipulate[
 UnitConvert[a*endPoint + (1 - a)*startPoint, "Inches"], {a, 0, 1}]
```

The manipulate converts a point along a line to inches. It works for any setting of `a`, except `0.` and `1.`, where I get `UnitConvert[0. + Quantity[1., "Meters"], "Inches"]` instead of a proper length. Generally speaking, it seems that any expression that contains a dimensionless subexpression that can be 0 might break somewhere in your `Manipulate`, `Table` or `Animate`. This seems extremely fragile to me.

Is this a bug? Or am I using `Quantity` wrong? Should I avoid dimensionless expressions completely? Or avoid `Quantity` inside dynamic code?

Comment: Of course it should be 0ft! IMO new unit system is very incomplete. I would recommend this [package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/), it works way more better.

Comment: @swish: I'm actually thinking about using the old package instead of the new quantites. Less verbose and apparently less buggy. But I would have liked the deep integration into plots, calculus and so on.

Comment: Old package has the same integration. And this new `TargetUnits` for plots is buggy anyways.

Comment: @swish: Seems as if AutomaticUnits doesn't work in version 9 any more... I'll probably keep using the built-in Units package

Comment: I just removed `QuantityUnits` folder from _AddOns/Applications_. I don't know how to remove it properly :(.

Comment: @swish try putting ``Internal`$DisableQuantityUnits = True;`` in your `init.m`. This prevents the package from loading without forcing you to actually remove it. ``AutomaticUnits` `` will then work completely normally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it would've been nice if the package handled it automatically, it can be fixed with a simple overloading of `Quantity`:

```
Unprotect@Quantity;
Quantity /: (0 | 0.) Quantity[_, unit_] := Quantity[0, unit]
Protect@Quantity;
```

You can add this to your `init.m`, so that you don't have to define it each time. You can test your examples with this:

```
0. Quantity[1, "Meters"]
(* 0 m *)

0 Quantity[1, "Meters"]
(* 0 m *)
```

Comment: Is this a safe overload. It sure looks like nothing could go wrong, but are there any catches?

Comment: +1, this looks very promising. But wouldn't it make more sense to tag the assignment to `Quantity` instead of `Times`? Then ordinary multiplications not involving quantities wouldn't be slower or behave differently, right? I've tried `Quantity /: (0 | 0.) Quantity[_, unit_] := Quantity[0, unit]` and it seems to work just as well.

Comment: @nikie Yes, overloading `Quantity` is preferable. I'll update it.

Comment: This code looks strangely familiar :) +1.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Not sure what you mean, but I'll take the +1 :)

Comment: I meant [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15338/simpler-input-for-the-new-unit-support/15343#15343) fo mine :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ha! Hadn't seen that one yet... well, now I must upvote that :)

Comment: @rm-rf Great minds think alike? Thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 5):

Not a full answer since I need to sleep :) but more of an observation, which might help. It seems to have to do with the fact that `0` and `0.` are not the same in Mathematica.  This simple example shows it

```
     UnitConvert[0. + Quantity[5, "Meters"], "Inches"]
     (*-->  UnitConvert[0. + Quantity[5, "Meters"], "Inches"]  *)
```

while

```
     UnitConvert[0 + Quantity[5, "Meters"], "Inches"]
     (*---> Quantity[25000/127, Inches]  *)
```

So, to get your `Manipulate` to work, just do this

```
startPoint = Quantity[1, "Meters"];
endPoint = Quantity[5, "Meters"];
Manipulate[UnitConvert[Rationalize[a]*endPoint + (1 - Rationalize[a])*startPoint, 
  "Inches"], {a, 0, 1}]
```

And now no problems at any end.

PS. see the Trott book, page 149-150 "For programming" , very useful on differences between `0` and `0.` in Mathematica.

**edit**

The reason why

```
UnitConvert[0*Quantity[1,"Meters"],"Inches"]
```

fails with

```
During evaluation of In[153]:= Quantity::compat: 0 and Inches are incompatible units >>
```

Is the same reason why

```
UnitConvert[0,"Inches"]
```

fails

```
During evaluation of In[154]:= Quantity::compat: 0 and Inches are incompatible units >>
```

Since `0` times almost anything in Mathematica gives `0`, and `0` has no units. So conversion failed. I think this is different from the above examples, where the issue above was in the `addition` as can be seen

```
0. + Quantity[5,"Meters"]  (*---> 0. +5m *)
```

while

```
0 + Quantity[5,"Meters"] (* ---> 5m *)
```

Comment: Only in this special case. Take `UnitConvert[a * startPoint, "Inches"]` instead - this will not work for `0` or `0.`

Comment: (I think) Rationalizing `0.` to `0` works because `0 + _` is automatically simplified to `_`, but `0. + _` is not. the bug is still there, it's just masked in this special case.

Comment: *0 times almost anything in Mathematica gives 0*. That's exactly the problem. If any dimensionless subexpression becomes 0, Mathematica will throw away all the units and further calculations might fail (although they won't always fail, as you demonstrated).

Comment: This has come up in the past.  I posted the following message on comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica back in 2010:

"While testing Mathematica 8 on some heritage code, I found a problem
which a colleague traced to a behavioral change in Times[].
Specifically, the documentation for Times[] states that "0 x evaluates
to 0, but 0.0 x is left unchanged."  This appears to be true in
Mathematica 7 but not in Mathematica 8 (at least not under Mac OS X
10.6.4).
I have informed Wolfram about this change (bug?)"
I don't think I ever received a satisfactory answer (they acknowledged the problem, but no fix).

Comment: There would be two ways to fix this: Either make sure that `Times[0, Quantity]` doesn't simplify to `0`, or make sure that Quantity and UnitConvert treat 0 as a value that can have any dimension. That would have been possible without changing the whole core. That's how the old Units package and AutomaticUnits apparently solved the same problem.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi: the fact that the behavior changed from MMA7 to MMA8 leads me to think that the problem can be fixed.