# Insert a Quantity Unit literal in TraditionalForm

Tags: keyboard, units

Is there a keyboard shortcut for creating something like the result of this:

```
Quantity["Kilograms" * ("Meters")^2 / ("Seconds")^2]
```

After copying the result to a `TraditionalForm` field it looks like this (line 3):

[image]

Is there a shortcut for creating something like this in `TradionalForm` without having to type `Quantity[..., ...]` directly?

Comment: This may be related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/inputting-abbreviated-units