# Getting all physical units with prefixes

Tags: units, wolfram-alpha-queries

How we can get the list with all physical units and prefixes from WolframAlpha and make symbols from the result to be equal their corresponding quantities like described in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15338/simpler-input-for-the-new-unit-support)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is what you seek, but you can use `Trace` to investigate in a call to `Quantity`. Then you extract the essence

```
Quantity["Newtons"];
StringReplace[Names["CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`*"], 
 "CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`" ~~ r_ :> r]
```

and you get *some kind of list* ;-)

[image]

Comment: +1 LOL Now I really have to find my glasses

Comment: Amazing. And what planet are some of these from, `FluctuationStrengthUnit`, `HanksWool`, ... `PleasureUnit`?

Comment: @alancalvitti a few of those are dimensions like "LengthUnit", possible results of `UnitDimensions`. Probably the units are those that are also in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18526/109) list. That Q seems like a duplicate of this one

Comment: However, mapping `UnitDimensions` to the unit list doesn't produce all those weird things such as PleasureUnit, so no idea where that comes from.

Comment: @Rojo, A New Kind of Unit.