# Built-in unit strings recognized by Quantity?

Tags: units

It’s great that [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantity.html) can utilize Wolfram Alpha to interpret unit strings that it doesn’t recognize, but I need my code to work on machines that do not have Internet access.

Is there a complete list of built-in (i.e. canonical) unit strings recognized by [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantity.html)?

Better yet, is there a programmatic way to produce such a list?

Comment: Good question! I hope Wolfram notices this question and intends to make the Quantity capability stand alone (I often use compound units and almost always run into this issue).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is certainly the optimal way of obtaining the list you are looking for

```
Quantity;QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules[[1, All, 1]]
```

**EDIT for v10** (thanks @DavidCreech)

In v10 this undocumented variable format has been changed into an association, whose keys are the units.

```
Quantity; Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules]
```

Comment: Haha, I just came here to post this! Damn you fellow spelunker!

Comment: FWIW, this seems to me the optimal way to obtain this list, which incidentally *is* appropriate.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I trust your judgement, editing

Comment: Haha, nice! The `Dispatch` object from which this list is extracted is actually built from the downvalues of ``CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`KnownUnit0Q``, which is the canonical arbiter of whether a unit is valid or not. But since this doesn't change after the ``QuantityUnits` `` package is loaded, recovering the list as you do here is surely the most direct approach.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @Rojo Note that in version 10 an association is used, so use `Quantity; Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules]` if you are using 10.

Comment: In v12.2, it seems `QuantityUnits\`$UnitList` is simpler?

Answer (score 9):

As a partial answer the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantity.html) says:

> Supported units include all those specified by [NIST Special Publication 811](http://www.nist.gov/pml/pubs/sp811/index.cfm).

This is repeated in [Unit Discovery](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnitDiscovery.html).  It also states:

> Unit interpretation requires internet connectivity, and can entail additional evaluation time. If speed is a concern, it is advisable to use the canonical unit specification, which can be found using `InputForm`.

Answer (score 4):

For Mathematica 12.2.

These two are equivalent

```
Sort@Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules] == 
 Sort@QuantityUnits`$UnitList
(*True*)
```

There are also

```
QuantityUnits`$UnitAlternateStandardNameReplacements
```

contains something like `Celsius` which is not contained in `$UnitList`. Most of these units are readily usable in `Quantity` except few cases need internet connection for interpretation.

There are also `UnitShortName` information in QuantityUnits`$UnitTable

```
shortUnitAssoc = QuantityUnits`$UnitTable // Query[;; , "UnitShortName"] // 
 Select[# =!= None &];
```

which contains `"Milligrams" -> "mg"`, `"Kilograms" -> "kg"`, `"Meters" -> "m"` etc. Some of these short unit are readily usable like `Quantity[1,"mg"]`.