# How do I seamlessly migrate from the older Units package to Mathematica 9's Quantity objects?

Tags: version-9, units

I have several notebooks that make use of the `Units` package and would like to be able to work simultaneously with the older units and `Quantity` objects introduced in version 9. What is my lowest-overhead method for updating units to `Quantity` objects?

Comment: @rm -rf, thanks for the edits.  Much better now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have mined the `Units` package for the names of all units defined therein and correlated them to the built-in strings recognized by `Quantity`(referenced [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18526/built-in-unit-strings-recognized-by-quantity)).  I then define a new function `Quantify` to convert the old school units into `Quantity` objects.

```
unitRules = 
 Dispatch[{Abampere -> Quantity[1, "ABAmperes"], 
   Abcoulomb -> Quantity[1, "ABCoulombs"], 
   Abfarad -> Quantity[1, "ABFarads"], 
   Abhenry -> Quantity[1, "ABHenries"],
   Abmho -> Quantity[1, "ABMhos"],
   Abohm -> Quantity[1, "ABOhms"],
   Abvolt -> Quantity[1, "ABVolts"],
   Acre -> Quantity[1, "Acres"],
   Amp -> Quantity[1, "Amperes"],
   Ampere -> Quantity[1, "Amperes"], 
   AMU -> Quantity[1, "AtomicMassUnit"], 
   Angstrom -> Quantity[1, "Angstroms"],
   Apostilb -> Quantity[1, "Apostilbs"], 
   ArcMinute -> Quantity[1, "ArcMinutes"], 
   ArcSecond -> Quantity[1, "ArcSeconds"],
   Are -> Quantity[1, "Ares"], 
   AssayTon -> Quantity[1, "AssayMetricTons"], 
   AstronomicalUnit -> Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], 
   Atmosphere -> Quantity[1, "Atmospheres"], 
   AtomicMassUnit -> Quantity[1, "AtomicMassUnit"], 
   AU -> Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], 
   AvoirdupoisOunce -> Quantity[1, "Ounces"], 
   AvoirdupoisPound -> Quantity[1, "Pounds"], 
   Bag -> Quantity[1, "BagsUK"], 
   BakersDozen -> Quantity[1, "BakersDozens"], 
   Bale -> Quantity[1, "BalesOfCotton"],
   Bar -> Quantity[1, "Bars"],
   Barn -> Quantity[1, "Barns"],
   Barrel -> Quantity[1, "Barrels"],
   Barye -> Quantity[1, "Baryes"], 
   Baud -> Quantity[1, "Bits"/"Seconds"], 
   Becquerel -> Quantity[1, "Becquerels"],
   Biot -> Quantity[1, "Biots"],
   Bit -> Quantity[1, "Bits"],
   BoardFoot -> Quantity[1, "BoardFeet"], 
   BohrMagneton -> Quantity[1, "BohrMagneton"], 
   Bolt -> Quantity[1, "BoltsWidthCotton"], 
   BritishThermalUnit -> Quantity[1, "BritishThermalUnitsIT"], 
   BTU -> Quantity[1, "BritishThermalUnitsIT"], 
   Bucket -> Quantity[1, "BucketsUK"], 
   Bushel -> Quantity[1, "BushelsUS"],
   Butt -> Quantity[1, "ButtsUK"],
   Byte -> Quantity[1, "Bytes"],
   Cable -> Quantity[1, "CableLengthsUK"], 
   Caliber -> Quantity[1, "Calibres"], 
   Calorie -> Quantity[1, "LargeCalories"], 
   Candela -> Quantity[1, "Candelas"],
   Candle -> Quantity[1, "Candelas"],
   Carat -> Quantity[1, "Carats"], 
   Celsius -> Quantity[1, "DegreesCelsiusDifference"], 
   Cental -> Quantity[1, "Centals"], 
   Centigrade -> Quantity[1, "DegreesCelsiusDifference"], 
   Centimeter -> Quantity[1, "Centimeters"], 
   Century -> Quantity[1, "Centuries"], 
   Chain -> Quantity[1, "EngineersChains"], 
   ChevalVapeur -> Quantity[1, "ChevalVapeurs"], 
   Cicero -> Quantity[1, "Ciceros"],
   Circle -> Quantity[1, "Circles"],
   Cord -> Quantity[1, "Cords"],
   Coulomb -> Quantity[1, "Coulombs"],
   Cubit -> Quantity[1, "Cubits"],
   Cup -> Quantity[1, "Cups"],
   Curie -> Quantity[1, "Curies"],
   Dalton -> Quantity[1, "Daltons"],
   Day -> Quantity[1, "Days"],
   Decade -> Quantity[1, "Decades"],
   Denier -> Quantity[1, "Denier"],
   Didot -> Quantity[1, "DidotPoints"], 
   DidotPoint -> Quantity[1, "DidotPoints"], 
   Diopter -> Quantity[1, "Diopters"],
   Dozen -> Quantity[1, "Dozens"], 
   Drachma -> Quantity[1, "AeginaDrachmes"], 
   Drop -> Quantity[1, "MetricDrops"],
   Dyne -> Quantity[1, "Dynes"], 
   ElectronVolt -> Quantity[1, "Electronvolts"], 
   Ell -> Quantity[1, "Ells"],
   Ephah -> Quantity[1, "Ephahs"],
   Erg -> Quantity[1, "Ergs"], 
   Fahrenheit -> Quantity[1, "DegreesFahrenheitDifference"], 
   Farad -> Quantity[1, "Farads"],
   Fathom -> Quantity[1, "Fathoms"],
   Feet -> Quantity[1, "Feet"],
   Fermi -> Quantity[1, "Fermis"],
   Fifth -> Quantity[1, "Fifths"],
   Firkin -> Quantity[1, "FirkinsUS"], 
   FluidDram -> Quantity[1, "FluidDrams"], 
   FluidOunce -> Quantity[1, "FluidOunces"],
   Foot -> Quantity[1, "Feet"],
   FootCandle -> Quantity[1, "FootCandles"], 
   Fortnight -> Quantity[1, "Fortnights"], 
   Furlong -> Quantity[1, "Furlongs"],
   Gal -> Quantity[1, "Gallons"],
   Gallon -> Quantity[1, "Gallons"],
   Gamma -> Quantity[1, "Gammas"],
   Gauss -> Quantity[1, "Gausses"], 
   Geepound -> Quantity[1, "GeepoundsMass"], 
   Gilbert -> Quantity[1, "Gilberts"],
   Gill -> Quantity[1, "Gills"],
   Grade -> Quantity[1, "Grads"],
   Grain -> Quantity[1, "Grains"],
   Gram -> Quantity[1, "Grams"], 
   GramWeight -> Quantity[1, "GramsForce"], 
   Gravity -> Quantity[1, "StandardAccelerationOfGravity"], 
   GrayDose -> Quantity[1, "Grays"],
   Gross -> Quantity[1, "Gross"], 
   GrossHundredweight -> Quantity[1, "LongHundredweights"], 
   Hand -> Quantity[1, "HandsUnit"],
   Hectare -> Quantity[1, "Hectares"], 
   Hefner -> Quantity[0.92, "Candelas"],
   Henry -> Quantity[1, "Henries"],
   Hertz -> Quantity[1, "Hertz"], 
   Hogshead -> Quantity[1, "HogsheadsUS"], 
   Horsepower -> Quantity[1, "HorsepowerMechanical"], 
   Hour -> Quantity[1, "Hours"], 
   Hundredweight -> Quantity[1, "ShortHundredweights"], 
   ImperialGallon -> Quantity[1, "GallonsUK"], 
   ImperialPint -> Quantity[1, "PintsUK"],
   Inch -> Quantity[1, "Inches"], 
   InchMercury -> Quantity[1, "InchesOfMercury"], 
   Jeroboam -> Quantity[1, "Jeroboams"], 
   Jigger -> Quantity[1, "Jiggers"],
   Joule -> Quantity[1, "Joules"],
   Kayser -> Quantity[1, "Kaysers"],
   Kelvin -> Quantity[1, "Kelvins"], 
   Kilogram -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], 
   KilogramForce -> Quantity[1, "KilogramsForce"], 
   KilogramWeight -> Quantity[1, "KilogramsForce"], 
   Knot -> Quantity[1, "Knots"],
   Lambert -> Quantity[1, "Lamberts"], Last -> Quantity[1, "LastsUK"],
    League -> Quantity[1, "Leagues"], 
   Libra -> Quantity[1, "PortugueseLibras"], 
   LightYear -> Quantity[1, "LightYears"], 
   Link -> Quantity[1, "EngineersLinks"],
   Liter -> Quantity[1, "Liters"],
   LongTon -> Quantity[1, "LongTons"],
   Lumen -> Quantity[1, "Lumens"],
   Lumerg -> Quantity[1, "Lumergs"],
   Lux -> Quantity[1, "Lux"],
   Magnum -> Quantity[1, "Magnums"],
   Maxwell -> Quantity[1, "Maxwells"],
   Meter -> Quantity[1, "Meters"], 
   MetricTon -> Quantity[1, "MetricTons"],
   Mho -> Quantity[1, "Mhos"],
   Micron -> Quantity[1, "Microns"],
   Mil -> Quantity[1, "Mils"],
   Mile -> Quantity[1, "Miles"],
   Millennium -> Quantity[1, "Millennia"], 
   MillimeterMercury -> Quantity[1, "MillimetersOfMercury"], 
   Mina -> Quantity[1, "AeginaMinas"],
   Minim -> Quantity[1, "MinimsUS"],
   Minute -> Quantity[1, "Minutes"],
   Mole -> Quantity[1, "Moles"],
   Month -> Quantity[1, "Months"], 
   NauticalMile -> Quantity[1, "NauticalMiles"], 
   NetHundredweight -> Quantity[100, "Pounds"], 
   Newton -> Quantity[1, "Newtons"],
   Nibble -> Quantity[1, "Nibbles"],
   Nit -> Quantity[1, "Nits"],
   Noggin -> Quantity[1, "NogginsUK"], 
   NuclearMagneton -> Quantity[1, "NuclearMagnetons"], 
   Obolos -> Quantity[0.71538, "Grams"], 
   Oersted -> Quantity[1, "Oersteds"],
   Ohm -> Quantity[1, "Ohms"],
   Omer -> Quantity[1, "Omers"],
   Ounce -> Quantity[1, "Ounces"],
   Parsec -> Quantity[1, "Parsecs"],
   Pascal -> Quantity[1, "Pascals"],
   Peck -> Quantity[1, "Pecks"], 
   Pennyweight -> Quantity[1, "Pennyweights"], 
   Percent -> Quantity[1, "Percent"], 
   Perch -> Quantity[1, "PerchesLength"],
   Phot -> Quantity[1, "Phots"],
   Pica -> Quantity[1, "Picas"],
   Pint -> Quantity[1, "Pints"], 
   Point -> Quantity[1, "DesktopPublishingPoints"], 
   Poise -> Quantity[1, "Poise"],
   Pole -> Quantity[1, "Poles"],
   Pondus -> Quantity[1, "DutchPonds"],
   Pony -> Quantity[1, "PoniesUS"],
   Pound -> Quantity[1, "Pounds"],
   Poundal -> Quantity[1, "Poundals"], 
   PoundForce -> Quantity[1, "PoundsForce"], 
   PoundsPerSquareInch -> Quantity[1, "PoundsForce"/"Inches"^2], 
   PoundWeight -> Quantity[1, "PoundsForce"], 
   PrintersPoint -> Quantity[1, "DesktopPublishingPoints"], 
   PSI -> Quantity[1, "PoundsForce"/"Inches"^2], 
   Puncheon -> Quantity[1, "PuncheonsUS"], 
   Quadrant -> Quantity[1, "RightAngles"], 
   Quart -> Quantity[1, "Quarts"],
   Quintal -> Quantity[1, "Quintals"],
   Rad -> Quantity[1, "Rads"],
   Radian -> Quantity[1, "Radians"], 
   Rankine -> Quantity[1, "DegreesRankine"], 
   RegisterTon -> Quantity[1, "RegisterTons"], 
   Reyn -> Quantity[1, "Reyns"],
   Rhes -> Quantity[1, "Rhes"],
   RightAngle -> Quantity[1, "RightAngles"],
   Rod -> Quantity[1, "Rods"],
   Roentgen -> Quantity[1, "Roentgens"], 
   Rontgen -> Quantity[1, "Roentgens"],
   Rood -> Quantity[1, "Roods"],
   Rope -> Quantity[1, "Ropes"], 
   Rutherford -> Quantity[1, "Rutherfords"], 
   Rydberg -> Quantity[1, "Rydbergs"],
   Seam -> Quantity[1, "SeamsUK"],
   Second -> Quantity[1, "Seconds"],
   Section -> Quantity[1, "Miles"^2], 
   Shekel -> Quantity[1, "ShekelsMass"], 
   ShortHundredweight -> Quantity[1, "ShortHundredweights"], 
   ShortTon -> Quantity[1, "ShortTons"],
   Shot -> Quantity[1, "Shots"], 
   SiderealSecond -> Quantity[1, "SiderealSeconds"], 
   SiderealYear -> Quantity[1, "SiderealYears"], 
   Siemens -> Quantity[1, "Siemens"],
   Skein -> Quantity[1, "Skeins"],
   Slug -> Quantity[1, "SlugsMass"], 
   SolarMass -> Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], 
   Span -> Quantity[1, "SpansLength"], 
   Stadion -> Quantity[1, "GreekStadions"], 
   Stadium -> Quantity[1, "GreekStadions"], 
   Statampere -> Quantity[1, "StatAmperes"], 
   Statcoulomb -> Quantity[1, "StatCoulombs"], 
   Statfarad -> Quantity[1, "StatFarads"], 
   Stathenry -> Quantity[1, "StatHenries"], 
   Statohm -> Quantity[1, "StatOhms"], 
   StatuteMile -> Quantity[1, "Miles"], 
   Statvolt -> Quantity[1, "StatVolts"], 
   Steradian -> Quantity[1, "Steradians"], 
   Stere -> Quantity[1, "Steres"],
   Stilb -> Quantity[1, "Stilbs"],
   Stokes -> Quantity[1, "Stokes"],
   Stone -> Quantity[1, "Stones"], 
   SurveyMile -> Quantity[1, "SurveyMiles"], 
   Tablespoon -> Quantity[1, "Tablespoons"], 
   Talbot -> Quantity[1, "Talbots"], 
   Talent -> Quantity[1, "AeginaTalents"], 
   Teaspoon -> Quantity[1, "Teaspoons"],
   Tesla -> Quantity[1, "Teslas"],
   Therm -> Quantity[1, "Therms"],
   Ton -> Quantity[1, "ShortTons"], 
   TonForce -> Quantity[1, "ShortTonsForce"], 
   Tonne -> Quantity[1, "ShortTons"],
   Torr -> Quantity[1, "Torr"],
   Township -> Quantity[1, "Townships"], 
   TropicalYear -> Quantity[1, "TropicalYears"], 
   TroyOunce -> Quantity[1, "TroyOunces"],
   Tun -> Quantity[1, "Tuns"],
   UKGallon -> Quantity[1, "Gallons"],
   UKPint -> Quantity[1, "Pints"],
   Volt -> Quantity[1, "Volts"],
   Watt -> Quantity[1, "Watts"],
   Weber -> Quantity[1, "Webers"],
   Week -> Quantity[1, "Weeks"],
   Wey -> Quantity[1, "WeysMass"], 
   WineBottle -> Quantity[0.7576778, "Liters"], 
   XUnit -> Quantity[1, "XUnits"],
   Yard -> Quantity[1, "Yards"],
   Year -> Quantity[1, "Years"]}];

prefixRules = 
  Dispatch[{Yotta -> 10^24, Zetta -> 10^21, Exa -> 10^18, 
    Peta -> 10^15, Tera -> 10^12, Giga -> 10^9, Mega -> 10^6, 
    Kilo -> 10^3, Hecto -> 100, Deca -> 10, Deci -> 10^-1, 
    Centi -> 10^-2, Milli -> 10^-3, Micro -> 10^-6, Nano -> 10^-9, 
    Pico -> 10^-12, Femto -> 10^-15, Atto -> 10^-18, Zepto -> 10^-21, 
    Yocto -> 10^-24}];

 Quantify[expr_]:=expr/.prefixRules/.unitRules
```

`Quantity` objects and old school units can be freely mixed

```
Quantify[{(2 Centimeter^3)/(Quantity[1.199, 
  "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3] Quantity[344.0, "Meters"/"Seconds"]^2), 
  30. Micro Farad}]
```

yields

```
{Quantity[0.00140959, (("Centimeters")^4 ("Seconds")^2)/("Kilograms")], 
    Quantity[0.00003, "Farads"]}
```

Comment: +1 goes w/o saying. This is great stuff. Can you share the code to extract all units? WRI will surely add more (new) units, so how to catalogue them dynamically?

Comment: @alancalvitti My intent was to allow the use of the units that were defined in the old (pre-9) Units package. Presumably, this package is no longer maintained as Quantity has taken over that functionality, so this was a one-time event performed manually.  By manually, I mean with sloppy, throw-away code.  However, if you like this approach, you are welcome to add your own units into the dispatch table.

Comment: I also made sure that any Quantity I used were among those stored locally rather than those that make a call to the Wolfram servers.  I have to work behind a proxy sometimes and entering proxy settings during execution of coded solutions is not acceptable.

Comment: I meant the new versions. Can you use the same approach to list the new built in units. I don't know of a way to extract them with, say, `Names[Quantity[_, _]]` --> `Quantity::unknunit : Unable to interpret unit specification"`. What's your approach?

Comment: Yes, glad you mention the over the network units - which are slow even w/ no firewall. Ideally would like a list of both types.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  I was converting from the static list of known units in the Units package (which is stored as a readable .m file) to the new Quantity objects, not the other way around.