# A complete list of quantities in Mathematica 9/10?

Tags: units

Often times when I'm traveling I don't have internet access and cannot reliably use Wolfram Alpha for unit look-up. Additionally, Alpha can always choose to change how it interprets the units I enter, and I'd rather have a notebook that is stable to any server-side changes.

So, I was wondering if there is anywhere I can look up a complete (or near-complete) list of units, constants, etc., that could be summoned using the `Quantity` function (e.g. `Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]`). I did not find such a list anywhere in the documentation, aside from the now-deprecated "Units" package. Is there an easy way to extract such a list? At the moment when I don't have internet access I have to resort to trial and error.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18526/built-in-unit-strings-recognized-by-quantity?rq=1, so this is a dupe. Should I delete my question or just let it be closed?

Comment: I'd say just let it be closed - having more ways to search for a thing is often good.