# How to find all InformationUnits by code method?

Tags: units

As I know, the `"Megabytes"` and `"Gigabits"` both are `"InformationUnit"`:

```
UnitDimensions["Megabytes"]
UnitDimensions["Gigabits"]
```

> {{"InformationUnit", 1}}

> {{"InformationUnit", 1}}

Is there any method to find all unit in `"InformationUnit"` by code method?

Comment: At a minimum, in addition to "bit" and "byte" there is "trit".  Look at `UnitDimensions /@ {"bit", "byte", "trit"}` and `Outer[UnitConvert, {"bit", "byte", "trit"}, {"SIBase", "SI", "Imperial", "Conventional", "Metric"}]`

Comment: You could try `WolframAlpha["Bytes", "PodCells"]` and `WolframAlpha["Bytes", "PodCells"][[{4, 5}]]`

Comment: @eldo Does this method apply to `AmountUnit` and `"LengthUnit"`?

Comment: @eldo Done.....

Comment: +1 - Very nice and difficult to find

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select[QuantityUnits`$UnitList, 
 MemberQ[First /@ UnitDimensions[#], "InformationUnit"] &]
```

> {ADSLDownstreamSpeed,ADSLUpstreamSpeed,AdvancedFormatHardDiskSectorSizes,AIT1NativeCapacity170Meter,AIT1NativeCapacity230Meter,AIT1TurboNativeCapacity,AIT2NativeCapacity170Meter,AIT2NativeCapacity230Meter,AIT2TurboNativeCapacity,AIT3ExNativeCapacity,AIT3NativeCapacity,AIT4NativeCapacity,AIT5NativeCapacity,AIT6NativeCapacity,AITENativeCapacity,ARCnetSpeed,ATMSpeed,Bans,Bits,Bluetooth2Speed,BluetoothSpeed,Bytes,CellularDigitalPacketDataSpeed,CompactDiscs,Crumbs,Decibans,Deckels,DigitalSignal0Speed,DualLayerBluRays,DualLayerDVDs,DVDMinusR,DVDMPlusR,DVDSpeed,E1Speed,E2Speed,E3Speed,E4Speed,E5Speed,EDGESpeed,Ethernet1000BaseTSpeed,Ethernet100BaseTXSpeed,Ethernet10BaseTSpeed,Exabits,Exabytes,Exbibits,Exbibytes,FastTokenRingSpeed,FaxSpeed,FDDICDDISpeed,Filesystem16MBlockSizes,Filesystem1MBlockSizes,Filesystem2MBlockSizes,Filesystem4MBlockSizes,Filesystem512KBlockSizes,Filesystem8MBlockSizes,FireWire100Speed,FireWire1600Speed,FireWire200Speed,FireWire3200Speed,FireWire400Speed,FireWire800Speed,FiveGSpeed,FloppyDisks35InchMacDS,FloppyDisks35InchMacHD,FloppyDisks35InchMacSS,FloppyDisks35InchPC,FloppyDisks525Apple,FloppyDisks525PC360,FloppyDisks525PC800,FourGSpeed,Gibibits,Gibibytes,Gibioctets,Gigabits,Gigabytes,GigaDialEquipmentMinutes,Gigaoctets,GPRSSpeed,HDTVSpeed,Hebdobits,Hebdobytes,Hellabits,Hellabytes,Hexits,HighSpeedTokenRingSpeed,HolographicVersatileDisc,HSCSDSpeed,HundredVGAnylanSpeed,InformationPages,ISDNBRISpeed,ISDNNSpeed,ISDNPRISpeed,ITUV32Speed,ITUV34Speed,ITUV90Speed,J3CSpeed,J3Speed,J4Speed,Kibibits,Kibibytes,Kibioctets,Kilobits,Kilobytes,Kilokibibytes,Kilooctets,Lactabits,Lactabytes,LandlineSpeed,LTEPeakDownlinkSpeed,LTEPeakUplinkSpeed,Macrobits,MagneticDiskBlockSizes,MaxWiFiSpeed80211a,MaxWiFiSpeed80211b,MaxWiFiSpeed80211g,MaxWiFiSpeed80211n,Mebibits,Mebibytes,Mebioctets,Megabits,Megabytes,Megaoctets,Metcalfes,Millibits,MiniCompactDiscs,Myriabits,Myriabytes,Nats,Nibbles,Nickels,OC12Speed,OC1536Speed,OC18Speed,OC192Speed,OC1Speed,OC24Speed,OC256Speed,OC3072Speed,OC36Speed,OC384Speed,OC3Speed,OC48Speed,OC768Speed,OC96Speed,OC9Speed,Octets,OpticalDiskBlockSizes,Pebibits,Pebibytes,Pebioctets,Petabits,Petabytes,Petaoctets,Quadbits,Quettabits,Quettabytes,Ronnabits,Ronnabytes,RS232Speed,SATA10Speed,SATA20Speed,SATA30Speed,SDSLSpeed,SingleLayerBluRays,SingleLayerDVDs,StarLANSpeed,T1CSpeed,T1FractionalSpeed,T1Speed,T2Speed,T3CSpeed,T3Speed,T4Speed,T5Speed,Tebibits,Tebibytes,Tebioctets,TenGigabitEthernetLANSpeed,TenGigabitEthernetWANSpeed,Terabits,Terabytes,Teraoctets,ThreeGSpeed,TokenRingSpeed,TraditionalCDROMSectorSizes,TraditionalDVDSectorSizes,TraditionalHardDiskSectorSizes,Trits,Trytes,TS3DSpeed,UMTSSpeed,USB10Speed,USB1lSpeed,USB20Speed,USB30Speed,USB31Speed,Vendekabits,Vendekabytes,WCDMAWTDMASpeed,WeizsaeckerUralternatives,Wekabits,Wekabytes,Wydes,Xennabits,Xennabytes,Yobibits,Yobibytes,Yottabits,Yottabytes,Zebibits,Zebibytes,Zettabits,Zettabytes}

---

Relatec [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18526/built-in-unit-strings-recognized-by-quantity)

Answer (score 3):

Short and idiomatic:

Use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) to find all the elements of `` QuantityUnits`$UnitList `` that has [`UnitDimensions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitDimensions.html)  [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) (`===`) to the [`UnitDimensions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitDimensions.html) of `"Bytes"` (`UnitDimensions["Bytes"]`)

```
Select[
    QuantityUnits`$UnitList
    ,(UnitDimensions[#]===UnitDimensions["Bytes"])&
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
k = QuantityUnits`$UnitList;
v = UnitDimensions@QuantityUnits`$UnitList;
assoc = Association[Table[k[[i]] -> v[[i]], {i, 1, Length@k, 1}]];
Select[assoc, 
  MemberQ[#[[1]], "InformationUnit"] || 
    MemberQ[#[[2]], "InformationUnit"] || 
    MemberQ[#[[3]], "InformationUnit"] &] // Quiet
```