# List of supported units in Mathematica 9

Tags: version-9, physics, units

Is there a list of supported units in Mathematica 9 documentation? I personal haven't found any; even the physical constants (newly supported as units in 9) can only be found in [compatibility information](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/PhysicalConstants.html). It is quite strange that Wolfram didn't even compile a list of units for the documentation.

Comment: I just spent minutes to figure out atomic mass unit is named "AtomicMassUnit"... I guess I was pretty stupid but lack of documentation is really frustrating.

Comment: Have you seen [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15893/187)?

Comment: Check [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18529/109)