# Extract function parameters from "unevaluated" FormBox

Tags: units

I want to get the abbreviation for a `Unit` from its full name eg. `"Newtons"` => `"N"`.

Using `TraditionalForm` on `Quantity` will show the abbreviation and doing the following will show the code returned by `TraditionalForm`:

```
Quantity["Newtons"] // TraditionalForm // InputForm
(* =>
FormBox[TemplateBox[{1}, QuantityUnit, 
   DisplayFunction -> 
    (TooltipBox[StyleBox[RowBox[{#1,  ,  N}], 
        ShowStringCharacters -> False], Unit: newtons] & ), 
   InterpretationFunction -> 
    (RowBox[{Quantity, [, RowBox[{#1, ,, "Newtons"}], ]}] & ), 
   SyntaxForm -> Mod], TraditionalForm]
*)
```

How can I extract the `N` from the above without parsing the string generated by using `ToString` on it?

Comment: The boxes didn't copy completely; this is not valid input.  Since I don't have `Quantity` in version 7 I cannot build your output for myself.  Could you try copying again with a different method?  Try copying as Input Text if you didn't use that already.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That gives the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was made possible by [rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf)'s help.

This may do what you want.  I shall use `ToBoxes` to get valid box data to work with:

```
boxes = ToBoxes[ Quantity["Newtons"] ];

Cases[
  boxes, 
  StyleBox[RowBox[{__, label_}], "QuantityUnitTraditionalLabel"] :> label,
  -1
] // First
```

> ```
> "\"N\""
> ```

You can use `ToExpression` or (for simple abbreviations) `StringTake["\"N\"", {2, -2}]` to strip the embedded quotation marks yielding `"N"`.

---

Using the answer of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15893/187) allows you to quickly create a browser for all possible units:

```
Quantity["Newtons"];
units = StringReplace[Names["CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`*"], 
   "CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`" ~~ r_ :> r];

Manipulate[
 ToExpression @@ 
  Cases[MakeBoxes[#, TraditionalForm] &@Quantity[u], 
   StyleBox[RowBox[{__, label_}], "QuantityUnitTraditionalLabel"] :> 
    label, -1], {{u, "Newtons"}, units}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]