# Units: Custom-defined units possible?

Tags: customization, units

Converting between revolutions per minute (RPM) and revolutions per second (RPS) is not straightforward for me in Mathematica.

I know that $1\; \text{RPM} = \frac{2\; \times\; \Pi\; \text{Radian}}{\text{Second}\; \times\; 60}$. To get RPS then, it is just a matter to remove the factor of $60$ in the denominator.

Taking a numerical example, I can convert say $500$ RPM to Hertz as follows:

$[\text{Convert}[\frac{500\; \times\; 2\; \times\; \Pi\; \text{Radian}}{\text{Second}\; \times\; 60}, \text{Hertz}],9]$

which gives me $52.3597776\; \text{Hertz}$

But now if I want to convert $500$ RPM to RPS, the following does not work as in the `Convert` command, the second argument has also **numerical values** in it:

$[\text{Convert}[\frac{500\; \times\; 2\; \times\; \Pi\; \text{Radian}}{\text{Second}\; \times\; 60}, \frac{2\; \times\; \Pi\; \text{Radian}}{\text{Second}}],9]$

which gives me as output: $\frac{52.3598776\; \text{Radian}}{\text{Second}}$ instead of the desired answer of about $8.33\:$ . The factor of $2\; \Pi$ is the troublemaker.

So how to do an appropriate conversion from RPM to RPS?

**update**:

I am using version 9.

Comment: Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: If You are using _Mathematica 9_ You can try `UnitConvert[]` function. I'm using ver. 7.0 so I can't check if it works in Your case.

Comment: @Wojciech yes, `N@UnitConvert[Quantity[500,"Revolutions"/"Minutes"], "Revolutions"/"Seconds"]` does give the result 8.333...

Comment: That one was pretty straightforward, since it is in the documentation center :)

Comment: As does `UnitConvert[Quantity[500., "RPM"], "RPS"]`

Comment: It works because the units are recognized, but that doesn't answer the general question of defining a custom unit

Comment: The title is about custom defined units, but the rest of the question is rather about specific problem, especially with a question 'how to do an appropriate conversion from RPM to RPS?' at the end. I can't see how defining new units could help in converting rpm to rps.

Comment: @Wojciech It can. If, instead of all this mess with units, one simply writes down 1*r/min /. min -> 60*s /. r -> RPS*s, where r stays for "rotation", min for "minutes" and s for "seconds" one immediately gets the answer.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Then the easiest way would be to create a package with custom units, where this might help http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15338/simpler-input-for-the-new-unit-support , or download AutomaticUnits package from here: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/ , I think rpm should be there.

Comment: @Wojciech I disagree. It is much shorter to write "s" then "Second". If one makes serious calculations he ends up with tens of different variables with dimensions. To write them all along with with their dimensions may, of course, be a pleasure, though a masochistic one. In a package one necessarily has to generalize on one hand, and to think about possible use of already reserved names on the other hand. The cost is a great awkwardness, like the one with complete names of units I pointed out above.

Comment: @Wojciech Continuation: In contrast, in any real-science calculation one only needs a part of the full set of units, and, consequently, only a part of the full set of rules for their transformations. Indeed, one does not need any package to fast write down and fast apply a simple rule, as I did above.