# Custom units Compatible with Conversions

Tags: function-construction, units, custom-notation

I am writing a *Mathematica* Palette to work with units, and am wondering if anyone knows a way to define new units outside of the standard ones that come with *Mathematica* 9. I do know of the `IndependentUnit` command

```
Quantity[3, IndependentUnit["Boxes"]]
```

which in this specific case makes sense to be non-convertible, but I want to add convertible units such as `Smoots`, `Batmans`, and `MingDynasties`. I found an old package that seemed to do this (["Automatic Units package"](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/)), but I couldn't get any of the functions to work, even when copied from the included documentation. What I want is to be able to convert from user-defined units to more conventional ones and back again without manually doing it, i.e

```
Unit[Smoots,67 Inches] (*defines 1 Smoot to be equal to 67 inches*)
UnitConvert[5 Smoots, Inches] (*would return 335 inches*)
UnitConvert[335 inches,Smoots] (*would return 5 Smoots*)
```

Since this has been done in a package before, I don't foresee this being impossible, but I am a fairly novice *Mathematica* Programmer, and could be very mistaken. If anyone has any insight, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `QuantityUnits\`` is a complete rewrite of the `AutomaticUnits\`` package and has little in common with it, so the documentation examples are certainly not going to be compatible. To make matters difficult, the source code of `QuantityUnits\`` is encrypted. Bottom line, I think `QuantityUnits\`` has a fixed set of units that it can work with, and would need to look into how to circumventing this to define new ones. It requires downvalues to be defined on a number of different symbols to get it working.

Comment: Same question, essentially: [(39006)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39006/units-custom-defined-units-possible)

Comment: If any long-standing user of the site wants to have a try at implementing the custom unit, I have some information that may be valuable but which it isn't possible to give here. Email me: `"1:eJxTTMoPCpZjYGDIz0nNLk7MSymKL0osLigtyczLL3OozE3MzNFLzs8FAAAzDfw="`