# Can you make the new "Choose color scheme" helper larger?

Tags: color, interface

Mathematica 10 has a cool new "color data chooser" feature:

[image]

My question is: Can you make that window larger? Right now, I can only see 3-4 color schemes at once, even though all 51 gradients would easily fit on the screen at once, if the windows were a little larger, and showed more than one row, e.g. like this:

```
Labeled[ColorData[#, "Image"], #] & /@ ColorData["Gradients"] // 
  Partition[#, 5, 5, {1, 1}, {}] & // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: @Öskå: I thought questions regarding the current version don't get a version tag? That's how it was handled e.g. on this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15338/242 (version tag for version-9 was removed by rcollyer)

Comment: I have no idea.. :) All the recent question regarding issues with _v10_ get the _v10_ tags, that's all I know :) I guess Mr.Wizard could tell you more :)

Comment: @Öskå nikie is right; see also [this old meta Q](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80/5)

Comment: @rm-rf Although I think it would be great to have a tag for all the new stuff coming up with the _v10_. Like I said, most of the recent questions **were** tagged, but I've just noticed that you untagged them.. :)

Comment: @Öskå These toys are cool _now_, but the site is for long-term archiving... they'll be old and standard toys in a year or when v11 comes :)

Comment: @rm-rf Then we need an auto removing tag? I bet Community can remove tags after a few months :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression that generates that GUI element is contained in the file:

```
FileNameJoin[
 {$InstallationDirectory,
  "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "ColorSchemeSelector.tr"}]
```

After making a back-up you can edit that file as you see fit.

I don't have time to dig into it now and make a nice improvement but I confirmed that editing works by changing the fifth line from the bottom to read `ImageSize->{500, 800}`.

Comment: Great! I can make the list longer by replacing `ImageSize -> {Full, {200}}` with `ImageSize -> {Full, {600}}` in 3 places (for gradient, indexed and physical). But I can't simply make it multi-column, because `ListPicker` doesn't support that.

Comment: Damn! You're Mr.Wizard for a reason.

Comment: @seismatica <|:-D

Comment: After playing around with the tr file, I find this works for me: (1) edit the 5th-from-end line from `ImageSize->{180, Automatic}` to `ImageSize->{180, 600}`, then (2) using the Replace All utility in your text editor, replace every instances of `{Full, {200}}` in the file into `{Full, {500}}`. The first step seems to change the height of the white suggestion box, while the second seems to change the height of the content within that box, hence 600 for the former and 500 for the latter to prevent the content to spill out of the box. All credits to Mr.Wizard and nikie for suggestions.