# Is it possible to insert new colour schemes into ColorData?

Tags: color, customization

Because of the standards in my field, for many plots I need to use (or at least end up using) rather narrowly defined colour schemes, and in particular the Matlab "Jet" scheme, which is well described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152). I've typically done this by having a bit of boilerplate code which I include when necessary, and which creates the object `ColorData["Jet"]`:

```
Unprotect[ColorData];
ColorData["Jet"] = 
  Function[x, 
   Blend[Transpose[{
        {0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0}, 
        {Darker[Blue], Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Red, Darker[Red]}
   }], x]];
Protect[ColorData]
```

This is convenient because the new colour scheme can be handled using the same syntax as the in-built ones. In version 10, however, the choice of colour schemes has a bunch of additional niceties which I'd like to take advantage of it that's possible.

For example, the autocomplete menu for `ColorDat...` gives you instant access to a drop-down menu with images of the schemes' gradients, and which inserts `ColorData["gradient-of-your-choice"]` when you click OK.

[image]
[image]

Similarly, when you evaluate such `ColorData` objects, they come out with a nice preview of the gradient.

[image]

So, my question is: is it possible to take advantage of this structure by 'injecting' additional data into `ColorData`, so that custom colour schemes come up in the choices and behave in the same way as in-built ones?

Comment: Related: [(54648)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54648/121)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Extending `ColorData`

For some background consider reading [this bookmarked conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/conversation/internal-colordata-functions-j-m-mr-wizard).

The color scheme data itself is accessed through the definition of this Symbol:

```
DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes
```

The data is located by use of the list defined in:

```
DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNames
```

That is to say the scheme is extracted using (slightly simplified):

```
Pick[colorSchemes, colorSchemeNames, "SchemeName"]
```

Therefore these two sources must be kept synchronized.

These Symbols have no definition until `ColorData` (or similar) is first used therefore they must be "preloaded" before you make any modification or it will simply be overwritten during initialization.

Looking at the structure of one of the gradient entries in that data we can mimic it:

```
DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes[[150]]
```

> ```
> {{"MintColors", "mint colors", {}}, {"Gradients"}, 1, {0, 1}, {RGBColor[
>   0.465278, 0.97641, 0.637812], . . . RGBColor[0.913603, 0.61886, 0.788739]}, ""}
> ```

Customization:

```
ColorData[1];

new = {{"Primaries", "", {}}, {"Gradients"}, 
   1, {0, 1}, {Purple, Hue[0.6], Green, White, Yellow, Orange, Red}, ""};

AppendTo[
  DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes,
  new
];

AppendTo[
  DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNames,
  new[[1, 1]]
];
```

Test:

```
ColorData["Primaries"]
```

[image]

So we can successfully add a gradient scheme.  However this scheme does not appear in the Gradients pop-up menu shown in your question.

## Extending the Color Scheme Selector

The Color Scheme Selector is loaded from the system file found here:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, 
  "SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/ColorSchemeSelector.tr"}]
```

Unfortunately I don't know of a way to extend this menu apart from editing that file.  The elements are not dynamically loaded from `colorSchemes` but instead hard-coded directly in that file.  The structure seems fairly apparent with repeating sections of the form:

```
"Rainbow" -> 
 Grid[{{Spacer[6], 
    Pane[Style["Rainbow", 10], {117, 14}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
     ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"], Spacer[6]}, {Spacer[6], 
    Graphics[Raster[
      CompressedData[
       "1:eJwVVH . . . "], {{0, 0}, {1, 0.17094017094017094`}}], {ImageSize -> {130, 
        Automatic}, ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {6, 0}}, ImagePadding -> 0, 
      PlotRangePadding -> 0}], Spacer[6]}}, {Alignment -> {Left, {Center, Top}}, 
   Frame -> None, ItemSize -> {{0.5, {2 -> Automatic}}, Automatic}, Spacings -> {0, 0}}]
```

I heavily abridged the `CompressedData` content for display here.  As you can see the gradient is stored as a `Raster` rather than being generated from the gradient scheme itself.

That section formats as:

[image]

Later I shall try to find a way to modify this menu without editing this system file.  (*Edit: I never found a way.*)

Comment: One option is to create a custom palette which will dynamically load the color schemes on startup. This way probably should be preferred over editing the built-in palette.

Comment: @Alexey That's a good idea though it is not what the OP asked for.  I at least like to try to answer the actual question before or in addition to proposing alternatives.  Have you already implemented something like that?

Comment: But it is rather interesting if you find a way to modify the loaded built-in palette *on the fly* in-memory without editing the file.

Comment: After re-reading the question I realized that dynamical loading of the color schemes may not be the best choice: it requires additional communication between the FrontEnd and the Kernel which easily can lead to significant delay and even hanging-up of the FrontEnd. I'll try to see if the file `ColorSchemeSelector.tr` is loaded only once for session or every time the user requests that menu.

Comment: My quick experiments with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645) show that unfortunately the file `ColorSchemeSelector.tr` is loaded from the disk *every time* a user requests the menu.

Comment: It might be of some interest that according to Process Monitor *Mathematica* reads the file sequentially by pieces of 4096 bytes and reading the whole file takes 0.5 second (!) on my not too slow machine.

Comment: @Alexey Your observation explains something.  I found that the resource is available via `FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"]` but unprotecting and modifying that definition does not affect the autocompletion pop-up menu.  Since it is loaded from disk every time (which seems very odd since it is already loaded into the front end) I think perhaps the best we can do is procure that menu ourselves with e.g. `FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"] // CellPrint`.

Comment: It is interesting that first evaluation of `FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"]` results in reading the whole file from the disk even after the menu was already accessed and used. Further evaluations of `FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"]` do not result in reading the file but requesting the menu does this in any case. What do you intend to do with the procured menu? As far as I can see the best what we can do is to create extended Palette based on this menu. I do not know a way to replace the autocomplete menu other than replacing the file `ColorSchemeSelector.tr`.

Comment: We can conclude from the above observations that the autocomplete menu and evaluation of the `FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"]` are completely independent things.

Comment: I have performed a search of sting "ColorSchemeSelector.tr" inside of *Mathematica* installation directory and found it only inside of the files "Mathematica.exe". It means that this name is hard-coded into the FrontEnd and cannot be changed.

Comment: I think that conversation has been linked to plenty of times on this site… :D

Comment: Does anybody know what the lone `1` in `... {"Gradients"}, 1, {0,1} ...` relates to? I can't see a value in that position that is not `1` in any of the gradients!

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Good question.  I don't know what that value represents.  I'll see if I can find out.

Comment: Might be nice to note that your solution under "Customization" is not in addition to OP @EmilioPisanty's `Unprotect[ColorData]`-based approach, but simply replaces it.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli digging in the code I found `Data format:
 {"StandardName", "Name", "AlternateNames"},
 "Collections", "ParameterCount",
 "Range",
 "ColorList",
 "AlternateRange",
 "OrderFunction"
 "PrivateNote"`.
For `"Named"` collections, `"Range"` should be the list of color names.