# ColorFunction -> Hue not respected?

Tags: plotting, color, complex

I am encountering a bizarre problem.  I'm trying to generate the complex phase plot of the (principal branch of) the square root function by using `DensityPlot` on the argument of the square root with `ColorFunction -> Hue`.

```
Arg[Sqrt[-1]]
```

gives $\pi/2$ as expected.  Then

```
Hue[Rescale[Arg[Sqrt[-1]], {-π, π}]]
```

gives [image: Hue[3/4]].

However,

```
DensityPlot[
      Rescale[Arg[Sqrt[x + I y]], {-π, π}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
      PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> Hue, Exclusions -> None]
```

produces

[image: Density plot of argument of square root function]

which is clearly painting $-1$ in red.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Try `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. Usually Mathematica rescales your values to (0, 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's look at what $\arg$ looks like in *Mathematica*:

```
Plot3D[Arg[x + I y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image: phase of a complex number]

Note that $\arg$'s codomain here is $(-\pi,\pi]$, and that the branch cut runs along the ray $(-\infty,0)$. Thus, when you use `Rescale[x, {-π, π}]`, values along the negative real axis ($\arg z=\pi$) get mapped to 1, and `Hue[1]` is of course a nice shade of red.

In this case, you'll want a preliminary application of $\bmod$ to $\arg$, to get results on the interval $[0,2\pi)$ and see the expected color wheel:

```
DensityPlot[Mod[Arg[x + I y], 2 π], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> Hue,
            Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: complex color wheel]

Note the conspicuous lack of a `Rescale[]`. This is due to the setting `ColorFunctionScaling` being set to `True` by default, which rescales the values of the function before they are fed to the `ColorFunction`; thus, `Hue[]` is only seeing values in $[0,1]$. If you set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, then you do need an explicit `Rescale[]`:

```
DensityPlot[Rescale[Mod[Arg[x + I y], 2 π], {0, 2 π}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
            ColorFunction -> Hue, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
            Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

which should yield the very same color wheel.

Finally, here is what $\sqrt{z}$ looks like when "domain colored":

```
DensityPlot[Mod[Arg[Sqrt[x + I y]], 2 π], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
            ColorFunction -> Hue, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: domain coloring of the square root function]

Last, but not the least, [this previous thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7275) on domain coloring might be of interest.

Comment: For interest's sake [here](http://i.imgur.com/SFwBCpI.png) is what the above looks like when colored with a [cyclic isoluminant](http://peterkovesi.com/projects/colourmaps/) colormap.

Comment: @Quantum, which of the color maps in that page did you use? I see entries for cyclic colormaps, and entries for isoluminant colormaps, but nothing with both properties.

Comment: Sorry, that was misleading! It's not from that page, but its properties are well-described on that page. The map I've used is a line cut (at lightness 0.78) from the 2D map shown in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130794/6588). It just shows how with an isoluminant map the apparent lines, especially in the yellow and pink, disappear.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was interested in your colormap; would you consider writing a Q&A on this, then?

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I find that unless I use an explicit `Rescale` and set `ColorFunctionScaling->False`, it fails for the constant function whose value is i.

Comment: @José, yes, `DensityPlot[]` does not really work too well for functions that are "flat" or nearly so, I've found.