# Force a Scale on Custom ColorData Set for DensityPlot and ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I have created a custom Entry in ColorData as described by Mr. Wizard in [this Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57885/is-it-possible-to-insert-new-colour-schemes-into-colordata)

This works well until I need to force the Scaling of the ColorFunction to compare to other images.

A simple example would be:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y]*3, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 3}}], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Giving the following image:

[image]

But a new color set "Test", defined through:

```
ColorData[1];

new = {{"Test", "", {}}, {"Gradients"}, 
1, {0, 1}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 1], 
RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, ""};

AppendTo[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes, new];

AppendTo[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNames, new[[1, 1]]];
```

does not allow formatting along the lines of ColorData[{"Test",{min,max}}], resulting in:

```
ColorData::notent: {Test,{0,3}} is not a known entity, class, or tag for ColorData. Use ColorData[] for a list of entities.
```

How can I force a certain scaling on a Custom ColorData function?

This Syntax using {min,max} was very convenient, as I could write functions with scaling defined through MinMax[data].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a pure function with Rescale[] fixed it in the end.

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y]*3, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Test", Rescale[#1, {0, 3}]] &),
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Though I'm still wondering why the inserted ColorData does not share the same properties as the default ones.