# Soften colours in `DensityPlot`

Tags: plotting, color

I have a `DensityPlot` given by

```
DensityPlot[Cos[\[Pi] x] Cos[\[Pi] x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -10, 10}, 
ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

[image]

I like the colour scheme, but would prefer the blues and yellows to be 'washed out', as though they were partially transparent.

How do I do this? It seems to me that it ought to be simple. But I tried

```
DensityPlot[Cos[\[Pi] x] Cos[\[Pi] x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -10, 10}, 
ColorFunction -> "LighterBlueGreenLighterYellow"]
```

and it turned the whole plot purple and white...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the color function by using `ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]`, and you can also get it with `Blend["BlueGreenYellow", x]` where `x` is the value between 0 and 1 that we want to find a color for. We can make a new function out of this, e.g. together with `Lighter`:

```
DensityPlot[
 Cos[\[Pi] x] Cos[\[Pi] x y],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -10, 10},
 ColorFunction -> (Lighter[Blend["BlueGreenYellow", #]] &)
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We could apply `Lighter` again to get an even lighter plot. This time I'll do it with `ColorData`:

```
DensityPlot[
 Cos[\[Pi] x] Cos[\[Pi] x y],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -10, 10},
 ColorFunction -> (Lighter@Lighter[ColorData["BlueGreenYellow", #]] &)
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To only wash out blue and yellow but not green, we need to determine what green is. This is the color scheme that we have:

```
BarLegend["BlueGreenYellow", LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we determine that values between 0.6 and 0.8 are green, then we could do this:

```
lighter[x_Real] := If[
  0.6 < x < 0.8,
  ColorData["BlueGreenYellow", x],
  Lighter@ColorData["BlueGreenYellow", x]
  ]

DensityPlot[
 Cos[\[Pi] x] Cos[\[Pi] x y],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -10, 10},
 ColorFunction -> lighter
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We could also create a more complicated color function that has smooth boundaries, e.g. not sharp cutoffs at 0.6 and 0.8. Perhaps one way to go in this direction would be to get the colors that are blended in this color function and then lighten those that don't appear green.

To get the colors of the color scheme, we can use the method described by Mr. Wizard [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57893/731):

```
Position[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes, "BlueGreenYellow", \
Infinity]

(* Out: {{166, 1, 1}} *)
```

This means that the colors are:

```
colors = RGBColor @@@ DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes[[166, 5]];
SwatchLegend[colors, Range@Length@colors]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We now make all colors lighter except for colors five and six:

```
lighterColors = Lighter /@ colors;
lighterColors = ReplacePart[lighterColors, 5 -> Part[colors, 5]];
lighterColors = ReplacePart[lighterColors, 6 -> Part[colors, 6]];

cf = Blend[lighterColors, #] &;

DensityPlot[
 Cos[\[Pi] x] Cos[\[Pi] x y],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -10, 10},
 ColorFunction -> cf
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We could use a continuous lighting factor. Let's say that we determined that green peaked at 0.7. Then we could determine a lighting factor curve that was 0 at this value and increased as we move away from it, e.g.

```
Plot[
 1 - PDF[NormalDistribution[0.7, 0.4], x],
 {x, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cf2[x_] := Lighter[
  ColorData["BlueGreenYellow", x],
  1 - PDF[NormalDistribution[0.7, 0.4], x]
  ]

DensityPlot[
 Cos[\[Pi] x] Cos[\[Pi] x y],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -10, 10},
 ColorFunction -> cf2
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a comparison between the `cf2` color function and the `BlueGreenYellow` color function, side by side:

```
Column[{
  BarLegend[{cf2[#] &, {0, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"],
  BarLegend["BlueGreenYellow", LegendLayout -> "Row"]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see that it washes out the blue quite well while keeping the green mostly as it was. We could have the lighting factor increase faster on the right side of the peak in order to wash out the yellow more, but it's complicated because the yellow is very close to the green in this color scheme.

Comment: Thank you @C.E.. I was hoping to leave the green untouched, and just wash out the blues and yellows. Is that possible?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward ok, well that's an interesting detail in the question. The problem is that you have a continuous range of colors between yellow, green, and blue. So what is to you green?

Comment: Presumably there's some kind of colour-picker somewhere? If that returned an RGB number or some such, then I'd be happy to specify each colour individually - but would need to know both how to pick the course and the syntax to specify them in the plot. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward I posted a couple of new ways of thinking about this. Hopefully one of them can help.

Comment: Totally. Wow. Many thanks.