# Customize ColorData function

Tags: plotting, color, style

I am trying to customize the color data

```
ColorData["AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

I want to make color data function of the gradient starting from the green to the white instead of the green to the yellow. So I want the output such that,

```
ColorData["MyColorFunction"]
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you inspect the `InputForm` of the `"ColorFunction"` property for `"AvocadoColors"` you see that it uses `Blend` with a list of colors:

```
ColorData["AvocadoColors", "ColorFunction"] // InputForm
```

> ```
> ColorDataFunction["AvocadoColors", "Gradients", {0, 1}, Blend["AvocadoColors", #1] &]
> ```

Similarly, for `"Rainbow"` and other gradient color schemes:

```
ColorData["Rainbow", "ColorFunction"] // InputForm
```

> ```
>  ColorDataFunction["Rainbow", "Gradients", {0, 1}, Blend["Rainbow", #1] & ]
> ```

The function `` DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument `` gives the list of colors used in `Blend`:

```
clist = DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument["AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

Now you can replace the last color with `White` and use with `Blend`:

```
mycolorFunc = Blend[Append[Most[clist], White], #] &;
```

This function retains the yellow tones in the middle of the list. Alternatively, you can have `White` play the role of `Yellow` in your new color scheme using blends of the second color with `White` to construct an alternative list of blending colors:

```
myclist  = Prepend[FoldList[Blend[{#, White},#2]&, clist[[2]], {1, 2, 3}/3] , clist[[1]]]
```

[image]

```
mycolorFunc2 = Blend[myclist, #]&;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> #, ImageSize -> Medium]& /@
  {"AvocadoColors", mycolorFunc[#3] &, mycolorFunc2[#3] &}]
```

[image]

```
Style[Row[LinearGradientImage/@{"AvocadoColors", mycolorFunc, mycolorFunc2}, 
 Spacer[10]], ImageSizeMultipliers->{1,1}]
```

[image]

To add your custom color function to the existing color schemes you can use [this answer by Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57893/125):

```
ColorData[1];
new = {{"myColorFunction", "", {}}, {"Gradients"}, 1, {0, 1}, myclist, ""};
AppendTo[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes,  new];
AppendTo[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNames,  "myColorFunction"];

ColorData["myColorFunction"]
```

[image]

***Examples:***

```
BarLegend["myColorFunction", LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> {400, 100}]
```

[image]

```
PieChart[Range[10], ColorFunction -> "myColorFunction"]
```

[image]

Comment: DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument is not working for me, do I need package? It gave me error "Pick::incomp" "Expressions {xxxxxxx} have incompatible shapes

Comment: @SaesunKim, it  works  both in v12 (Wolfram Cloud) and in version 9 (Windows10). What version/os are you using?

Comment: I am using 11, let me update the version and try again. Thank you

Comment: It is working, not because of the version. I just restart the MMA. Thank you