# Cutting a Color Scheme

Tags: color

I am trying to do a DiscretePlot3D with something similar like "TemperatureMap" Color Scheme, where, however, the white color should correspond to ca. 1/3 of the maximum value. Based on the previous [question with answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202152/customize-colordata-function) I have written something like this, which, however, does not work. More or less I simply cut the "TemperatureMap" Color Scheme by hand ... Any suggestion, what do I wrong?

```
clist = DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument["TemperatureMap"];
clist
```

[image]

[image]

```
mycolorFunc2 = Blend[myclist, #] &;
DiscretePlot3D[
 SurvivalFunction[
  MultivariatePoissonDistribution[5, {2, 3}], {x, y}], {x, 0, 15}, {y,
   0, 15}, PlotStyle -> Orange, ExtentSize -> Right, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[mycolorFunc2][#3][
     Rescale[#3, {0, 1}]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Comment: Try some simplified version `DiscretePlot3D[
 SurvivalFunction[
  MultivariatePoissonDistribution[5, {2, 3}], {x, y}], {x, 0, 15}, {y,
   0, 15}, PlotStyle -> Orange, ExtentSize -> Right, 
 ColorFunction -> (mycolorFunc2[Rescale[#3, {0, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`

Comment: It worked, thanks! Don't you want to write it as an answer?

Comment: No, it is a small thing. Nice plot design idea, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

```
colorFunc[quantile_: 1/3, colorscheme_: "TemperatureMap"] := 
 ColorData[colorscheme][If[# <= quantile, Rescale[#, {0, quantile}, {0, 1/2}], 
    Rescale[#, {quantile, 1}, {1/2, 1}]]] &

q = 1/3;

DiscretePlot3D[SurvivalFunction[MultivariatePoissonDistribution[5, {2, 3}], {x, y}], 
 {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}, 
 ExtentSize -> Right, 
 ColorFunction -> (colorFunc[q][#3] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 FaceGrids -> ({#, {{}, {q}}} & /@ {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}), 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Black, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, q, 1}}]
```

[image]

Use `q = 2/3` to get

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> (colorFunc[q, {"TemperatureMap", "Reversed"}][#3] &)` to get

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> (colorFunc[q, "RedGreenSplit"][#3] &)` to get

[image]

etc.