# How to adapt or mimic the AbsArgPlot default ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, complex, color

I like the way `AbsArgPlot` uses a default `ColorFunction` that cycles through the hues with much less variation in perceived brightness than just using `Hue[h,1,1]`. To illustrate:

```
psi = Exp[-x^2] Exp[10 I x];
AbsArgPlot[psi Abs[psi], {x, -3, 3}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: AbsArgPlot output]

Compare to doing it manually using `Hue[]`:

```
 Plot[Abs[psi]^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200, Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[x, Hue[Arg[psi]/(2 Pi)]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Plot output that mimics AbsArgPlot using Hue]

So I'm wondering how to use and/or adapt and/or mimic the default `AbsArgPlot` `ColorFunction` in other code. I'd especially like to come up with something similar that fades out to white as `Abs[f]` goes to zero, for use with `RegionPlot` in examples like this:

```
psi = Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]*Exp[5 I (x + y)];
RegionPlot[True, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Arg[psi]/(2 Pi), Abs[psi]^2, 1]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: RegionPlot of a complex-valued function of two variables]

Of course, I could fool around with formulas for saturation and brightness that depend on the `Arg` of the function, but obviously someone at Wolfram has already found formulas (or the equivalent) that work nicely. Any idea how I can get them? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The color function is a gradient `"MidShiftBalancedHue"`:

```
Plot[Abs[psi]^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200, Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> "MidShiftBalancedHue"]
```

[image]

This reproduces the `ArgAbsPlot`:

```
Plot[Abs[psi]^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200, Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["MidShiftBalancedHue"][
     Rescale[Arg[Block[{x}, psi /. x -> #]], N@{-Pi, Pi}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the `Block[{x},...]` isn't necessary. (Something messed up, I put in `Block`, and it got fixed. Must have fixed whatever it was accidentally. Hmm.)

Comment: Wow--thanks! I can't find anything about "MidShiftBalancedHue" in any Wolfram documentation, so I have to wonder how you know about it and whether it's something we can rely on working in the future.

Comment: @dvs (1) See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57885/4999, which reveals how these colors are managed. (2) The names for `ColorData` are stored in ``DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNames``; the data for this one may be found with ``Cases[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes, {{"MidShiftBalancedHue", ___}, ___}]`` -- you could save it if you're worried about it going away. (3) I started with ``? *`*ArgAbs*`` and use ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions`` on ``...`iArgAbsPlot`` and followed the code. (4) Even documented things change or go away, but undocumented is riskier.