# Problems with my units?

Tags: output-formatting

I have my own unit is called "Euros"

Input:5 Euros -3 Euros

Output:2 Euros

Input:5 Euros - 5 Euros

Output:0

How can I make to get 0 Euros?

Output: 0 Euros->That I want to get.!!!!!!!!

Comment: Are you using a version of MMA that doesn't recognize `Quantity` or is there some other reason for not using that function?

Comment: @bobthechemist. Yes im using MMA and don't  need Quantity function. In USA for peyment use a "dollars",in my country -"złoty",in European Union -"euros ".

Comment: MMA recognizes all of them: `Quantity[5, "Zloty"]-Quantity[5,"Euros"]+Quantity[5,"Dollars"]`. and `Quantity[5,"Euros"]-Quantity[5,"Euros"]` results in an output that is pretty close to what you want.

Comment: @rm-rf I think [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15343/7167) might be a better duplicate, since the OP appears to want "my own unit".