# How to make certain mathematical characters be written as bold by default?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

In a notebook, when writing `\[RightVector]` over a variable I always end up bolding it to make it more visible. But it'd be easier if it could be set up to bold that character by default.

I haven't ventured into setting key bindings yet (just starting out), but I'm wondering if it's possible to set the combination <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>vec</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to turn on bolding, insert the appropriate symbol, then turn off bolding. If there's an even easier way, that'd be even better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use `InputAliases` to style the replacements as you wish. I explained how to make auto replacements in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4326/5), but that was for a more specialized purpose.

As a simple example, you can do something like:

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], InputAliases -> 
    {"foo" -> MakeBoxes@Row[{
        Style[foo, FontColor -> Red, FontWeight -> Bold, 
            FontSlant -> Italic, FontFamily -> "Verdana"],
            \[VeryThinSpace]
        }]
    }
]
```

Now if you type <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>foo</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, it will show up as a bold, italic red `foo`.

Comment: I would also throw in a `Block` around `foo` if there's a chance of it also being a variable in the current context

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm having a bit of a problem using `\[RightVector]` as the text being styled though. It looks like it's the same problem with any operators as well. Do you know of any ways around that?

Comment: @user745434 I don't know the answer off the top of my head... I can try figuring it out later, when I have some time :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll tinker with it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use the following alias instead:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "vec"}] = OverscriptBox[
    StyleBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", FontWeight->Bold],
    "\[RightVector]"
];
```

Then, using the following key strokes: <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> produces:

[image]

where the letter `b` is bolded.