# Possible to apply a function without brackets?

Tags: front-end

I was just playing around with entering two dimensional forms of some expressions. As an example, I wanted to write `Integral[Cot[t],t]`. I got as far as `\[Integral]Cot[t] \[DifferentialD]t`.

But I would love to make it look even more natural by omitting the brackets around the `t`. Is there any `\[]` character that helps me do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you can use [`\[InvisibleApplication]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/InvisibleApplication.html). It's probably also worth knowing `\[InvisibleComma]` when writing expressions this way.

For example in your case:
`\[Integral]Cot\[InvisibleApplication]t \[DifferentialD]t`

Comment: This bit me once... see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1/) that I asked (also the very first question on this site). You might also find `\[InvisibleSpace]`, `\[ImplicitPlus]` and `\[InvisibleTimes]` useful if you choose to go this route, but be aware that these might make it very hard to debug and make it less readable for others.

Comment: @R.M Have you ever figured out what `\[ImplicitPlus]` is used for?

Comment: @sebhofer, Wolfram's example is `9\[ImplicitPlus]3<Ctrl-/>4` for 9-and-three-quarters written in its traditional numberical form.

Comment: Wow... mixed fractions. Haven't used that since elementary school ;-)

Comment: (Did I _actually_ type "numberical"? Sigh.)