# Syntax error in entering mathematical expression

Tags: syntax

I am trying to enter the following mathematical expression in code:

```
Subscript[Q, n, 2][
  n] = (1/2\[InvisibleComma]\[Mu][
       n]^2 Sqrt[\[Lambda]] (Cos[\[Mu][n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]]^2 + 
        Cosh[\[Mu][n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]]^2) + 
     3/2 \[Mu][
       n] Cos[\[Mu][n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] Cosh[\[Mu][
         n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] (Cos[\[Mu][
            n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] Sinh[\[Mu][n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] + 
        Cosh[\[Mu][n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] Sin[\[Mu][
            n] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]])) Cosh[\[Mu][n]^2/Sqrt[\[Lambda]]]
```

However, I get a syntax error in Mathematica:
[image]

Can anybody spot a reason why this might be happening?

Comment: Where did this expression come from? Do you have a reference where this formula is given?

Comment: It's tricky : You have a InvisibleComma just after the `1/2` !

Comment: Copy/patse your expression into an editor, then you can see the invisible comma.

Comment: @J.M. It arose as a coefficient in the solution to a PDE I am trying to solve.

Comment: @andre314 what is the point of an InvisibleComma?

Comment: "what is the point of an InvisibleComma" - it's intended for people who want to type subscripts of matrix/array entries without wanting to show the separating comma. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1) as well.